# Can't update Nvidia driver and having error near the end of the installation

Tags: drivers, nvidia, updates, update-manager, downloads

I had just got Ubuntu (first timer to Ubuntu so be very descriptive). I think there a problem with my Nvida update it won't let me update it. This is the name of the update in update manager NVIDIA binary xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library. When i attempt to install it, it starts out fine but near the end i get a window titaled package operation
failed

with these under the details

```
   installArchives() failed: Setting up nvidia-current (295.40-0ubuntu1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia-current
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/nvidia-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/nvidia-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/nvidia-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Processing quirk Latitude E6530
DEBUG:Failure to match Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. with Dell Inc.
DEBUG:Quirk doesn't match
DEBUG:Processing quirk ThinkPad T420s
DEBUG:Failure to match Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. with LENOVO
DEBUG:Quirk doesn't match
Removing old nvidia-current-295.40 DKMS files...
Loading new nvidia-current-295.40 DKMS files...
Error! DKMS tree already contains: nvidia-current-295.40
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.
dpkg: error processing nvidia-current (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 3
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-31-generic
Warning: No support for locale: en_US.utf8
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-current
Error in function: 
Setting up nvidia-current (295.40-0ubuntu1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia-current
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/nvidia-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/nvidia-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/nvidia-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Processing quirk Latitude E6530
DEBUG:Failure to match Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. with Dell Inc.
DEBUG:Quirk doesn't match
DEBUG:Processing quirk ThinkPad T420s
DEBUG:Failure to match Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. with LENOVO
DEBUG:Quirk doesn't match
Removing old nvidia-current-295.40 DKMS files...
Loading new nvidia-current-295.40 DKMS files...
Error! DKMS tree already contains: nvidia-current-295.40
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.
dpkg: error processing nvidia-current (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 3
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-31-generic
Warning: No support for locale: en_US.utf8
```

Comment: Related to https://askubuntu.com/q/996312/472560

Answer (score 3):

I had the same exact problem and it didn't get removed with sudo apt-get install -f or sudo apt-get update. I followed the instruction [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely) for purging NVidia drivers and it worked fine. You might want to try the same thing.