# How to uninstall manually installed Nvidia drivers?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, uninstall

How do I uninstall manually installed Nvidia drivers 310.14  and revert to Noveau.  I have Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: Just for the sake of precision, the correct syntax is: sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86-310.19.run -uninstall

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I uninstall a nvidia driver completely ?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of [How can I uninstall a nvidia driver completely ?](http://askubuntu.com/q/206283/107450) since that question is about drivers installed with the software centre or `apt-get`.

Answer (score 77):

Yeap, was going to say what Karasu said. Just to add some information. If the driver you downloaded is called for example `NVIDIA-Linux-x86-310.19.run` then you would run:

```
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86-310.19.run --uninstall
```

If you want to get the help for your Nvidia driver then do this:

`NVIDIA-Linux-x86-310.19.run --help` or a more extended version for it:

`NVIDIA-Linux-x86-310.19.run -A` which shows you the uninstallation option:

```
--uninstall
  Uninstall the currently installed NVIDIA driver.
```

There are a couple of other nice options in case you want to use them like:

`-a` - Accept License
`-s` - Silent Mode
`-q` - no questions
`-i` - Driver information
`--update` - Check Nvidia site and update to the latest

For cases where you use the CUDA installer, in the [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html) for it you can find more options on how to uninstall it, like this excerpt:

To uninstall the CUDA Toolkit, run the uninstallation script provided in the bin directory of the toolkit. By default, it is located in /usr/local/cuda-11.0/bin:

`sudo /usr/local/cuda-11.0/bin/cuda-uninstaller`

To uninstall the NVIDIA Driver, run nvidia-uninstall:

`sudo /usr/bin/nvidia-uninstall`

And others that can be seen when you run the --help parameter

[image]

Comment: And what if I accidentally deleted .run file?

Comment: @MKay you can download newer version of .run and it will delete older current version.

Comment: What if I installed the NVIDIA driver with the CUDA installer .run file? There is no --uninstall option

Comment: @D.Hot If you can give me a link to the installer I can test it out here.

Comment: you can download the installer here: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/10.2/Prod/local_installers/cuda_10.2.89_440.33.01_linux.run

Comment: @D.Hot I added some additional feedback based on your recommendations. Yes, it looks like it defers if using CUDA. Thank you.

Answer (score 17):

First you need the installation file. Then put it in your home folder, open a terminal and type

```
sudo ~/installation_file.run --uninstall`
```

Then restart your computer and your drivers will be completely uninstalled. If Unity don't load after the uninstallation, right click --> change desktop background, then click on "All Settings" on the left-top corner of the window. Then go to Software sources and install a proprietary driver from the list.

Comment: Yeap, was going to say this ^^.