# nvidia drivers fail completely after update to 3.5.019

Tags: nvidia, kernel, updates, xserver

I'm running a duel-screen set-up and need the proprietary drivers because the standard ones won't drive the second screen at full resolution.

After updating to 3.5.019, downloading the latest linux headers and re-installing "nvidia-current-updates" to trigger a recompile xserver/gdm won't load at all.

Help appreciated.

edit: extra information

Xorg.0.lgo

```
[     5.102] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[     5.102] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so
[     5.222] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[     5.222]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[     5.222]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[     5.222] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  304.51  Tue Sep 18 17:38:06 PDT 2012
[     5.222] Loading extension GLX
[     5.222] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[     5.222] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[     5.223] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[     5.223]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[     5.223]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     5.223] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  304.51  Tue Sep 18 17:18:40 PDT 2012
[     5.223] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[     5.223] (++) using VT number 7

[     5.225] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[     5.225] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[     5.225] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[     5.225] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     5.225]    compiled for 1.13.0, module version = 1.0.0
[     5.225]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[     5.225] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[     5.225] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[     5.225] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[     5.225] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     5.225]    compiled for 1.13.0, module version = 1.0.0
[     5.225]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[     5.225] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[     5.225] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[     5.225] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[     5.225] (**) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[     5.225] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[     5.225] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[     5.225] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[     5.226] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[     5.228] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module. Please see the
[     5.228] (EE) NVIDIA(0):     system's kernel log for additional error messages and
[     5.228] (EE) NVIDIA(0):     consult the NVIDIA README for details.
[     5.228] (EE) NVIDIA(0):  *** Aborting ***
[     5.228] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failing initialization of X screen 0
[     5.228] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[     5.228] (II) UnloadSubModule: "wfb"
[     5.228] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fb"
[     5.228] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
[     5.228] 
Fatal server error:
[     5.228] no screens found
[     5.228] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[     5.228] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[     5.228] (EE) 
[     5.229] Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

dkms status:

```
nvidia, 304.64, 3.5.0-18-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 304.64, 3.5.0-19-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-current-updates, 304.51, 3.5.0-19-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Appropriate section of kernel log:

```
Dec  5 13:37:06 ursus kernel: [    5.374507] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  304.64  Tue Oct 30 10:58:20 PDT 2012
Dec  5 13:37:06 ursus kernel: [    5.624054] NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 304.51, but
Dec  5 13:37:06 ursus kernel: [    5.624054] NVRM: this kernel module has the version 304.64.  Please
Dec  5 13:37:06 ursus kernel: [    5.624054] NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver
Dec  5 13:37:06 ursus kernel: [    5.624054] NVRM: components have the same version.
```

Comment: Please post the error output of X (usually in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`). Also, please post the output of `dkms status`.

Comment: I've tracked down the appropriate log entries and posted them above.

Comment: It seems you've got two `nvidia` drivers installed. Please tell the complete story here on your actions. Did you install the driver from a website and installed the package from Ubuntu without removing the old one?

Comment: It's possible. The last time this happened I tried a few approaches, this involved installing the NVIDIA drivers available from their website. The drivers started working again, but I was never able to work out exactly what fixed the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears you've messed up your kernel module configuration by installing both an upstream Nvidia driver as well as one from the Ubuntu repositories.

Now the "userland" Xorg libraries don't match the version of the kernel module and that's what you're seeing here in the Xorg error logs. I suggest you to take the steps below in order to revert to the ones provided by Ubuntu.

1. Uninstall the manually installed Nvidia driver. Refer to one of the many questions on this, e.g.

   [How to uninstall manually installed Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/q/219942/88802)
2. Uninstall all possible Ubuntu's Nvidia packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge 'nvidia-*'
   ```
3. List and remove the Nvidia kernel modules still installed (if any) at this point:

   ```
   dkms status
   dkms remove nvidia -k your-kernel-version-here
   ```

   *Repeat this until you see no Nvidia modules anymore using `dkms status`.*
4. Install from the repositories:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
   ```

   or if you need newer/recent versions:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates nvidia-settings-updates
   ```
5. Verify that the Nvidia kernel driver is build for your running kernel:

   ```
   dkms status | grep `uname -r`
   ```

   should produce e.g. `nvidia-current, 313.09, 3.8.3-030803-generic, x86_64: installed`.
6. Reboot.