# Boots into Console instead of GUI. GUI Wanted instead

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, xserver

My problem is that more often than not, when I boot into Ubuntu 12.04 it brings me to the Command-line prompt and asks for my login. After logging in I have to either try using

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.confg
```

Or

Reinstall the Nvidia 310 drivers in order to get my GUI back.

The error that the terminal puts out is `0 Screens found`. I am quite confused as to why that is. Is it because I have a DVI input? But after using the `sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.confg` command or reinstalling the Nvidia 310 drivers, it's works fine until next boot.

It's a bit inconvenient so if someone knows a fix to this, it'd be so so appreciated.

I apologize if there already is a question like this posted, but I did check and I couldn't see anything from what I saw.

I originally installed the Nvidia drivers using the jockey. (Additional Drivers) However now when I have to reinstall the drivers I just use the .run file from the website.

```
$ dkms status
nvidia, 310.32, 3.2.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-experimental-310, 310.14, 3.2.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed.

$ lspci -nnk | grep -IEA3 vga
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1188] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:095b]
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
        Kernel modules: nvidia, nvidia_experimental_310, nouveau, nvidiafb
```

---

Further system information:

- Alienware Aurora R4
- X79 Intel Chipset motherboard
- CPU: i7-3990K @ 3.20Ghz x 12
- GPU: Nvidia GTX 690
- Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! How did you install the Nvidia 310 drivers? Using a package or using a file from the Nvidia website? (The latter one is discouraged for the issue you just bump into). And can you include the output of `dkms status`? Provide all this information by *editing* your question.

Comment: @gertvdijk I originally installed the Nvidia drivers using the jockey. (Additional Drivers) However now when I have to reinstall the drivers I just use the .run file from the website. I am not sure how to get the [code] dkms status [code] so if you could tell me, that'd be awesome :)

Or to how to highly the code things that gunbert fixed for me :| Sorry, as I said I am new here, and quite a bit of a noob, unfortunately. 

Yes, I would like to boot to my GUI instead of the console. Sorry for any misunderstanding.

Comment: Just open a terminal (the *Terminal* application) and run the `dkms status` command. This lists the kernel modules versions installed handled by DKMS. You can then copy/paste the output. While you're at it, also run `lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 vga`. This lists all relevant information about your graphics card(s) installed. We can then see what you need to get it working. Remember to **edit** your question for this information (including that in your previous comment!). That is how this site works.

Comment: This is a Nvidia GeForce GTX 690 graphics card and should be supported very well by all current Nvidia drivers. The only reason for your current issue I can come up with is that the installation of the `.run` file screwed up your user space Xorg. Try using the steps in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/225763/88802) to get this straight again.

Comment: @gertvdijk That fixed it from what I saw! Thanks :) I really appreciate your help. Now that I have the answer I need, what do I do about this post? Sorry :|

Comment: possible duplicate of [nvidia drivers fail completely after update to 3.5.019](http://askubuntu.com/questions/225714/nvidia-drivers-fail-completely-after-update-to-3-5-019)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you've somehow messed up the system with two Nvidia drivers installed on the same kernel, as shown by the `dkms status` output. While the kernel module may load correctly, the "userland" Xorg part of the drivers are probably not matching the kernel module version now. Similar issue here: [nvidia drivers fail completely after update to 3.5.019](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225714/nvidia-drivers-fail-completely-after-update-to-3-5-019)

The card you have (Nvidia GeForce GTX 690) is perfectly supported by the current drivers shipped with Ubuntu (304 series). Installing the experimental drivers and mixing up with non-packages is very likely to break stuff as you've noticed, and confuse the package management. Lesson for the future: stick with packages from Ubuntu and if you do install Nvidia's driver from their site, uninstall the Ubuntu package.

I've already written an answer to this very similar issue/question posted. From the comments you reported this to be working. So, here is the reference to the answer:

- [Answer to: *nvidia drivers fail completely after update to 3.5.019*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225714/nvidia-drivers-fail-completely-after-update-to-3-5-019)