# problem updating to ubuntu 12.04.3

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, kernel

Followed instructions, all nvidia drivers gone. when I enter:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia settings
```

I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nvidia
E: unable to locate package settings
```

Comment: Somehow your Nvidia driver hasn't been installed properly. The kernel modules are updated, but the Xorg driver hasn't. Go to a virtual terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F1), log in, and provide the output of the following commands *in your question*: `dkms status` and `apt-cache policy nvidia-304*`. If the last command give too much output to type over, then only provide the `Installed:` line. Also have a look at this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/225763/88802 to completely reinstall Nvidia drivers manually.

Comment: Directly underneath your question are three links. The middle one reads "edit". Press it and you will be able to edit the text of your question and make additions to it. When done, press the "Save edits" button.

Answer (score 1):

In your question there is a missing hyphen in `nvidia settings`. Open the terminal and type the correct command which is:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```