# ubuntu 12.04 graphic error on boot after update from 10.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, xorg, lightdm

After an update to ubuntu 12.04 from 10.04, I have a strange problem: in grub menu if I select ubuntu kernel 3.2.0-58-generic the graphical interface just hangs there, I get this black screen with a blinking cursor at the top. It does react to crt+alt+F2 and ctr+alt+supr and then it reboots.

Then I select the other kernel which is the recovery and I enable networking and then drop to root shell I do `/etc/init.d/lightdm start` and then once it managed to boot normally and was working, kind of.

It's dell T7500 desktop with quadro 600 nvidia graphic card. I have blacklisted -nouveau and i am using nvidia driver 310.19 downloaded from their website.

I have previously purged nvidia and reinstalled xorg, gdm, lightdm several times, tried using gdm over lightdm ...

I have gnome3 desktop

I have then updated nvidia driver using `nvidia-installer --update` and now it's 310.20

After last reinstall of lightdm even `/etc/init.d/lightdm start` doesn't work.

I have tried to boot in failsafe graphic mode but still but it says no screen found (I have a screen obviously).

I have checked the /var/log/Xorg.failsafe.log and basically here are some of the messages:

loading --- vesa driver
Ignoring device with a bound kernel ...
Screens found but none with usable configuration

fatal server error 
no screens found

I have tried this: 
`sudo X -configure`
`sudo mv xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

then since it dind't work I ran `nvidia-xconfig`

Any other staff I could do? Thanks

EDIT: I installed dgm and then I did service gdm start and then startx and got the purple ubuntu screen which seems better than black screen but is not as ctr+alt+supr doesn't work

EDIT2: I have removed lightdm and installed gdm. So now if I try to boot normally it also crashes (shows weird screen half purle half black) but if I choose the recovery kernel and then slect the option boot normally it boots fine using gdm.

Comment: "weird screen half purple half black" does seem like a graphics driver issue. Why did you download the graphics driver from the Dell website? The nvidia-current driver from the Ubuntu Software Center for Ubuntu 12.04 is version 304.88.

Comment: it's the one we use at work and my colleagues did not have a problem with it. I will try tomorrow, maybe this will solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"weird screen half purple half black" does seem like a graphics driver issue. Why did you download the graphics driver from the Dell website? The nvidia-current driver from the default Ubuntu 12.04 repositories is version 304.88. To uninstall the Nvidia graphics driver follow the instructions in the answers to the question: [How to uninstall manually installed Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219942/how-to-uninstall-manually-installed-nvidia-drivers). To install the nvidia-current package open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Comment: thks, that solved my problem, you can also uninstall the manually installed driver with sudo nvidia-installer --uninstall