# Ubuntu 14.10 Nvidia Driver

Tags: nvidia

I upgraded my ubuntu 14.04 to 14.10 , and my nvidia gforce stopped working , and giving low resolution on both internal and external monitor!!!.
Is there any update for this Driver, as I am using version 340.46.

Regards

Qusai

Comment: Run the command: `ubuntu-drivers devices` from the terminal to show what graphics drivers for your graphics card are available to be installed from the Ubuntu Software Center. Wait at least one minute for the command to scan your computer and generate the list of drivers.

Comment: here is the output , == /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
model    : GF108M [GeForce GT 630M]
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000DE9sv00001043sd00002106bc03sc00i00
driver   : nvidia-304 - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
driver   : nvidia-331-updates - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-331 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-304-updates - distro non-free

Comment: nvidia-331 (the recommended graphics driver) is a very good graphics driver. First you have to uninstall the manually installed Nvidia version 340 graphics driver by following the instructions from [How to uninstall manually installed Nvidia drivers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/219942/how-to-uninstall-manually-installed-nvidia-drivers) (
Luis Alvarado's answer is a good answer) and then reboot and install the nvidia-331 graphics driver.

Comment: How did you install the 340.46? using xorg-edgers? or direct install?

Answer (score 2):

1. Run the command: `ubuntu-drivers devices` from the terminal to show what graphics drivers for your graphics card are available to be installed from the default Ubuntu repositories. Wait at least one minute for the command to scan your computer and generate the list of drivers.
2. Here is the output you got from running `ubuntu-drivers devices`:

   ```
   == /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 == 
   model    : GF108M [GeForce GT 630M] 
   vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation 
   modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000DE9sv00001043sd00002106bc03sc00i00 
   driver   : nvidia-304 - distro non-free 
   driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin 
   driver   : nvidia-331-updates - distro non-free  
   driver   : nvidia-331 - distro non-free recommended 
   driver   : nvidia-304-updates - distro non-free
   ```
3. nvidia-331 (the recommended graphics driver) is a very good graphics driver. First you have to uninstall the manually installed Nvidia version 340 graphics driver by following the instructions from [How to uninstall manually installed Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219942/how-to-uninstall-manually-installed-nvidia-drivers) (try Luis Alvarado's answer first) and then reboot and install the nvidia-331 graphics driver.