# Ubuntu not picking up graphics card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I recently built a PC and then installed Ubuntu. I noticed that when using the graphics card's ports Ubuntu doesn't pick it up so I have to use the CPU graphics card. I had the nvidia drivers for the card, but it doesn't seem to install. All help is much appreciated. Note: I'm very new to Ubuntu so if there is a different way to install drivers I wouldn't know Specs: i3-4360 GeForce GTX 750 H97M-D3H

Comment: Have you tried booting it up, going into the bios and switching to pice graphics? I had to do this on my new gigabyte board, as it did not automatically switch. Note: Drivers have literally nothing to do with your bios not switching over to your graphics card. You won't be able to install them until a nvidia card is detected.

Comment: Try running this query from the terminal: `ubuntu-drivers devices`. Does this command return any available NVIDIA drivers? Also see: [Ubuntu 14.10 Nvidia Driver](http://askubuntu.com/questions/542591/ubuntu-14-10-nvidia-driver) for example output of `ubuntu-drivers devices` for an NVIDIA GeForce GT 630M graphics processor.

Answer (score 0):

The standard Ubuntu Nvidia drivers generate some problems on slightly older *and* slightly newer Nvidia hardware.

If you want *more* then the standard Ubuntu repository drivers, install the [xorg.edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) PPA.  As the xorg.edgers group ask not to give installation instructions directly without linking to their page, this is the best I can do.

If you don't know what a PPA is or need some guidance after reading their page, leave a comment below.