# Cannot use CUDA, NVIDIA gpu is not detected, ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, cuda

I have ubuntu 14.04 and nvidia 660m. I have read several similar questions but non of them solved my problem. My problem is that either CUDA does not detect my gpu or I cannot login to ubuntu after reboot. Here's what I've done:

I used the xorg-edgers ppa to install the drivers via `apt`.

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-352`

Then I downloaded the same driver version from nvidia website and installed it because I read that I need the nividia's `.run` file to install cuda. Although it showed me that the pre-installation script failed, I forced it to install. And everything went fine and CUDA detected my gpu. (Without installing nvidia's .run file, CUDA fails to detect my gpu).

However, after rebooting, I could not pass the login screen any more.
To resolve it, I followed the instructions in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624966/cant-login-after-nvidia-driver-install-v-14-04) (uninstalling the `.run` file and uninstalling all nvidia drivers and reinstalling via ppa again) and I was able to login. However, now CUDA does not detect my gpu anymore. I tried reinstalling the `.run` file and the same happens. I can use CUDA just before I reboot and after reboot, I can't login.

How can I make CUDA work with NVIDIA?

Thanks

Comment: Please use CUDA from repository and then you can install the existing driver in 14.04 or latest via Graphics PPA. Make sure nvidia-modprobe is installed to make CUDA detect your GPU. Install nvidia-modprobe and reboot.

Comment: It didn't work. It doesn't detect my driver. CUDA only detects the driver when I install the driver from the .run file. However, if I do that, I get stuck at login screen.

Comment: modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:809 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='nvidia'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia': Function not implemented

Comment: I got it to work finally. Found the answer from here: https://codeyarns.com/2015/09/25/how-to-install-cuda-7-5-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

No answer about login issue. But to install cuda 7.5 you could use :

```
https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/blob/digits-3.0/docs/UbuntuInstall.md#repository-access
```

Comment: This didn't solve my problem.