# No graphical interface after updating

Tags: nvidia

After updating my 14.04.5 lts version, I have this message on screen

```
system-undevd[672]: failed to execute '/bin/systemctl''/bin/systemctl start -- no-block invidia persistenced': no such file or directory
```

After that, I obtain a black screen.
If I make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> I can have the Console and enter to my session.
I am asked if I want to upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04.01 lts

Finally I found the solution: ***sudo apt-get purge nvidia**** 
thank to this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624966/cant-login-after-nvidia-driver-install-v-14-04)

Comment: is this `'/binsystemtl''/bin/systemtl` truely the error your system prints?  there is only a command called `systemctl`

Comment: Finally I found the solution. sudo apt-get purge nvidia*