# NVIDIA graphics card not found anymore under Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, graphics, cuda

I have a GTX 1050 on my Thinkpad and did install the 455 driver. However, as I noticed that this driver was shipped with CUDA 11.1, which is incompatible with PyTorch, I tried to downgrade CUDA similiar to being described [here](https://medium.com/@praveenkrishna/downgrade-cuda-for-tensorflow-gpu-17831db59099) . However, now the gpu is not found by hwinfo or lshw or any other way. Even the installer form the NVIDIA homepage can't find the gpu anymore. It is present in a life session, but otherwise it seems to have disappeared from the OS.

I would be very happy if somebody could help me to find the gpu again, ideally with a working driver and CUDA 11.0.

Ubuntu-drivers devices is also returning nothing. My kernel version is 5.4.0-53-generic.

EDIT: Output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
    Subsystem: Lenovo UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

Note: this is not case in a live session, where the NVIDIA graphics card is listed.

Comment: Is your video card found under the 450 driver from the `graphics-drivers` PPA?  If so, you can download the `.run` file for the CUDA installer from their site.  Then when installing it, it will allow you to unselect the driver that comes with the CUDA installation allowing you to use whatever driver works for you.

Comment: The run-file from their website doesn't recognise the existence of a NVIDIA device on my laptop.

Comment: I wasn't asking about the .run file.  I was asking about the 450 drivers that are in the `graphics-drivers` PPA.  Please reread my comment above.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. When trying to install the 450 driver from the PPA, it fails; I get the message 'Error! Application of patch disable_fstack-clash-protection_fcf-protection.patch failed.'  and 'dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-450: nvidia-driver-450 depends on nvidia-dkms-450 (= 450.80.02-0ubuntu1); however:  Package nvidia-dkms-450 is not configured yet.' If I instead try to install 'nvidia-dkms-450' instead of the driver first, I get a similar error.

Comment: I recommend that you remove any NVIDIA driver that you have previously installed.  Make sure that your BIOS has the Secure Boot turned off.  Then I wrote this answer here to help with installing the 450 drivers and CUDA 11.1.  https://askubuntu.com/a/1288405/231142

Comment: Thank you for your advise. I deinstalled all previously present NVIDIA drivers following https://askubuntu.com/a/206289/1146897 and https://askubuntu.com/a/220729/1146897 and then did what you described in the link. After reboot 'nvidia-smi' however did still notify me that it cannot communicate with an NVIDIA-driver.

Comment: The last thing I can think of is possibly a kernel bug / issue.  I don't have the same system as you so I won't be able to duplicate your setup to write an answer.  However, what is the output of `uname -r`?  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1291864/edit) your question and add the output.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Both has been added to the question.