# How can I reinstall kernel-5.15.0-37 without Nvidia's driver

Tags: nvidia, kernel, gui

I have a notebook with a nvidia 2060 and Intel video. I made the mistake of trying to install nvidia's proprietary driver (version 515) using a .run file from it's site.

After that mistake I lost access to the GUI. I have to use an older kernel option at grub's menu to enter Ubuntu. I'm stucked with kernel-5.15.0-33 'cos I made another big mistake and select nvidia's auto compile option in very kernel upgrade. Yeah...I know...

I've tryed to remove kernel 5.15.0-37 files from /boot and grub menu and run:
#apt-get reinstall linux-image-5.15.0-37-generic linux-modules-5.15.0-37-generic linux-headers-5.15.0-37-generic with without sucess.

Already tryed
#sudo apt-get remove nvidia-*
#sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

But all these commands I run while I'm using kernel 5.15.0.33 'cos I don't have internet access using the newer one.

Can anyone tell me how can I install the newer kernel without nvidia's driver on it?

Thanks!

Comment: nvidia-smi command show me: NVIDIA-SMI 510.73.05 and Driver Version: 515.48.07

Comment: plese adapt this to your situation  https://askubuntu.com/questions/219942/how-to-uninstall-manually-installed-nvidia-drivers

Comment: Did you try to just delete the nvidia modules in /lib/modules/5.15.0-37-generic/updates/dkms ?  Then reboot and run the ...run -uninstall to get rid of them permanently.