My 22.04 LTS has lost its video drivers
First thing I have tried googling for an answer. None of the popular results are working for me.
Suggestions to use apt purge nvidia* is not working. It tells me those packages are recognized, and they are not installed.
Suggestions to use ubuntu-drivers autoinstall are not working. Some suggestions have steps after them. But that actual command is broken.
sudo ubuntu-drivers install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-drivers", line 513, in <module>
    greet()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1659, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-drivers", line 413, in install
    command_install(config)
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-drivers", line 187, in command_install
    UbuntuDrivers.detect.nvidia_desktop_pre_installation_hook(to_install)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UbuntuDrivers/detect.py", line 839, in nvidia_desktop_pre_installation_hook
    with_nvidia_kms = version >= 470
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'version' referenced before assignment


I tried to fix this with sudo apt install python3 --reinstall. That didn't work. I thought maybe the python3 library got corrupted if it's not recognizing these commands, that didn't work.
So then I tried sudo apt install ubuntu-drivers --reinstall and that's not a thing apparently.
sudo apt install ubuntu-drivers --reinstall
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ubuntu-drivers

I'm stumped on where to go from here.
Right now when I go to Additional Drivers, it grays out all the nvidia options and only lets me "choose" (not really a choice) Continue using a manually installed driver. And right now, my screen is mostly blue and white. Some red, magenta, and yellow are displayed, but it's mostly blues.
Edit:
Well, this shouldn't have been necessary, but I edited the file that threw this error:
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UbuntuDrivers/detect.py", line 839, in nvidia_desktop_pre_installation_hook with_nvidia_kms = version >= 470
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'version' referenced before assignment
So I put on a line 833         version = 0 and that seems to let me force myself through it. It does give me other errors now running sudo ubuntu-drivers install as it says
Error! Module version 535.183.01 for nvidia-peermem.ko
is not newer than what is already found in kernel 6.2.0-36-generic (550.90.07).
You may override by specifying --force.

So I'm going to force it, fingers crossed. And, nope, doesn't work, so not sure where I need to jump to put --force in.
sudo ubuntu-drivers install --force
Usage: ubuntu-drivers install [OPTIONS] [DRIVER]...
Try 'ubuntu-drivers install -h' for help.

Error: No such option: --force

Edit: This seems to actually have worked. I chose to ignore the errors in the second attempt because the workflow indicated it had downloaded all the other drivers, did a reboot hoping I could pick something out of the Additional Drivers tab, and it defaulted to the nvidia-driver-535-server-open one. It doesn't play nicely with my nvidia-smi for whatever reason, so trying another driver option. Somewhere in the past I had installed version 550 which doesn't show up among the options in additional drivers, so may just need to reinstall that to salvage nvidia-smi as I can't find a way to downgrade that version.

Where did you get kernel 6.2 from?

It got auto installed at some point. IDK. I've got multiple kernels and I never asked for them. Ubuntu just gave them to me.

Did you install the .run version directly from nVidia? You have to uninstall it using its directions. The .run is not recommended as you have to in effect reinstall it with every kernel update. https://askubuntu.com/questions/219942/how-to-uninstall-manually-installed-nvidia-drivers  Then you should be able to install from Ubuntu repository.

Thanks oldfred, that's right, I did use the .run. Before I got back to your comment, I had ran that route of uninstall all the nvidia stuff again, run the .run for version 550, and things are working; at least nvidia-smi says there's no version mismatch. If I run into issues down the road I'll get rid of 550 via the --uninstall flag on the .run file and go back to using Additional Drivers to be on 535.
