# After system update, screen size very small

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, updates, resolution, screen

Please help! I am pretty "newb" to linux and have no idea what to do.
I got the message "your system must reboot to complete updates" (or similar). After rebooting I am greeted with a giant login screen and my 2nd monitor isn't showing anymore.

After logging in, I can only see a part of my desktop -- one giant folder icon.
I can right click on the desktop  but gives me no option to change resolution or anything.

Any help would be wonderful.

PS: I am able to get a terminal window open. Luckily that ONE folder had a terminal shortcut I had put there. So if this can help troubleshoot, please advise.

EDIT 2: This got me back to Unity working and a nice resolution and both monitors:

```
 apt-get purge nvidia-current
 rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
 reboot now
```

Unfortunately, now I guess I don't have any HW accel for my graphics card? :(

Comment: Do you have a laptop? Does it have nvidia optimus?

Comment: No, it is a desktop. It is ASUS nVidia EN9600GT graphics card.

Comment: Do you have access to the screenshot utility? If not you can invoke it from the terminal with `gnome-screenshot`. It would be useful to see what your desktop looks like.

Comment: Not much to see. Basically if you zoomed in on the desktop background and had one giant-size folder icon. Pretty sure it was in 640x480 resolution. Unity wouldn't come up and compiz would crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Epilogue: 
Since it all seems to be working now, I should share what I did. Probably not the best way, but since I'm a newb I just went with what I can find. :)

1. Downloaded latest driver for 64bit / Linux from nVidia site
2. Download and install `linux-headers-3.5.0-19-generic`
3. Open terminal, change directory to where the .run from nvidia is downloaded
4. In terminal `chmod +x ...` the nvidia .run file
5. Reboot into recovery and login to recovery terminal
6. Run this command so nVidia script can write to stuff `sudo mount -o remount,rw /`
7. Run the nVidia script itself `sudo sh ./NVIDIA-...`
8. Ignore the first "... script failed..." error. Select option to allow it to blacklist, mostly "yes", "agree", etc.

I think that's everything. I didn't think of this, but had I not had the shortcut on my desktop to get to terminal, I could have just rebooted into recovery mode to get the terminal and while googling found a hotkey to get there too (CTRL + ALT + F1?).

After this everything seems to be working. I used `sudo nvidia-settings` from terminal to rearrange the physical location of my monitors properly.

**EDIT: This happened again after I updated my system...**

I ran this command that I found [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=843914):

`` sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r` ``

...and then basically repeated the entire process.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when I tried to remove my nVidia drivers.

You need to re-install `ubuntu-desktop` to get your normal screen back.

Refer here for complete information : [How can I uninstall a nvidia driver completely ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely)

Comment: +1 for the help, even though I did not use this to get it fixed, still useful.

Answer (score 1):

You could also check out `xrandr`.

With no option gives you a list of available defaults.

Update with i.e.:

`xrandr --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080`

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu under Oracle VirtualBox and same thing happened to me. Also I lost the mouse scroll abilites, etc.

What I did to fix the issue was re-installing the Guest Additions and all the functionality came back.