# screen resolution 14.04

Tags: 14.04, xorg, display, display-resolution

What's wrong with ubuntu? I've just upgraded my 12.04 to 14.04, and my screen resolution went to 1024x768.
xorg.conf is nowhere to find. not under /etc, not under /usr/share.

answers about changing screen resolution talk about xrandr and cvt.

Well I can use acronyms too. WTF, this is supposed to be easy to use. Windows has a right click on the desktop for screen resolution. And it lists all of the available reolutions for you. And you don;t loose any on upgrade.
And you find howto change the screen resolution everywhere and they are all correct, and they all work.

What;s wrong with ubuntu. Where can I get a straight simple, working answer how to get back my sane screen resolutions?

Comment: similar: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1970250 also: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2246700 also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/225121/after-system-update-screen-size-very-small ... I would go with full reinstall, I don't have good experience with OS upgrading nor with installing additional DE...

Comment: What are your GPU specs?

Comment: What's your video card? are you using open-source drivers? That may be the reason. "Full reinstallations FTW".

Answer (score 0):

Download [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/resolutionx/) package and install it with

```
sudo dpkg -i ResolutionX_1.0-0.deb
```

The description on the Sourceforge page provides some information about what it does, and the resolutions supported - if your required resolution is included, give it a shot :)

**NOTE** ResolutionX is a graphical frontend to `randr`, so if `randr` doesn't work with your PC, then the above won't, either.

Comment: All it does is use xrandr. I tried that manually, and I tried that with this package. Both [don;t] give the same results

Comment: @dbbd So you tried the above and it didn't work... right?

Comment: Right. None work. I also switch my monitor to connect to the on-board display-port, connected to the intel graphics (instead of the ATI radeon), after switching the display in the bios, and I still get only one, minimal resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the top right menu (little gears logo) > Settings > Display.
From there you'll be able to choose you resolution.

Comment: wishful thinking. but no. little gears logo-> little display icon->little display configuration->little resolution-icon, only one resolution.

Comment: @dbbd I have many configurations possible, so I thought you had too.