# Desktop broken: no launcher and no windows

Tags: unity, 12.10, nvidia

Today my laptop (Lenovo thinkpad t530) stopped booting at 'checking battery state' or a similar message. Loging-in to the regular console (alt-ctrl-f1) was possible, and I figured maybe it is some messed up driver thing.
So I reinstalled the nvidia-current drivers (apt-get install -reinstall).

This fixed the problem, however now after login in I see my desktop, but no launcher!
Furthermore if I start an application (ctrl-alt-t does work) I cannot move the application around (i.e. there is no real window, just the application itself) nor can I use atl-tab to switch applications.
Basicly I cannot work anymore because it is impossible to switch applications!

I tried a million things (unity-reset.py script, installing nvidia-experimental drivers, reinstalling the unity package), but nothing seems to fix this.

**EDIT:**

Ok, so I have sort of a solution now:
I uninstalled all Nvidia drivers (I remembered these cause problems in the past).
However this brought back the problem that the GUI won't boot beyond the test message  'checking battery state'. Choosing in the boot menu to boot an older kernel (3.5.0-19-generic instead of 3.5.0-21-generic) solved that problem.

So there are really two questions left though:

1. Why won't my system boot up properly all of a sudden (without picking an older kernel)?
2. Why does the GUI not work properly with the nvidia drivers (AFAIK my laptop has an Nvidia Optimus Graphics NVS 5400M videocard).

Answer (score -1):

I sort of had the exact problem with Unity after I installed nVidia drivers in 12.10.
I installed nVidia driver, rebooted and had a very low resolution and no Unity.

A friend of mine (an Ubuntu expert!) fixed it for me. He uninstalled the nvidia drivers. (I guess [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely) would help) the he installed [Nouveau](http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/UbuntuPackages) and everything was fine.

I hope it helps :-)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the links for reference.