# Poor performance for VMWare workstation 8.0 with Ubuntu 12.04 on ThinkPad w530

Tags: 12.04, performance, vmware, thinkpad

I am having ThinkPad w530 with 16 MB RAM and it has intel core i7 processor. I just installed VMWare Workstation 8.0 and I created a Virtual machine for Windows 7.0.

The performance of the virtual machine is very very slow, as I was using VMWare player 4.0 before with a vm of windows xp and it was great on another think pad with only 8 MB RAM.

I wonder if there is some mistake or some missing configuration that I need to do.

Here are my settings for the VM of Windows 7.0

Memory 8GB
Processor 4
     Virtualization Engine; Automatic

Network Adaptor: NAT

I wonder if any one can help me to fix this performance problem

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem is in the nvidia display driver. It seems it is not only the virtual machine, it is also the most of the applications on the host machine.

I removed the driver based on the instructions on this answer
[How can I uninstall a nvidia driver completely ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely)

These are the steps

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
echo 'nouveau' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the virtualization engine manually.  This fixed the problem for me. (Running Windows 8 x86_64 in VMware Workstation 9.0.2 on Arch Linux x86_64 3.9.2-1.