# How to fix Lubuntu GUI

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, gpu-driver

As the title states, my Lubuntu 13.10 install isn't working quite right currently. I installed everything just fine and was just getting comfortable with my setup. A few of the games I play were having graphics issues, so I was trying to fix that and in turn, broke everything.

When I boot, after I choose Lubuntu, all I get is a flashing horizontal cursor in the top left of my screen. I can switch to terminal mode via Ctrl + Alt + F1 and work from there, but that's it. This began after I installed a package from the command line (I want to say it was nvidia-331 perhaps?). After rebooting, I uninstalled that package and rebooted again to be greeted with the same sad situation. I tried installing nvidia-current which hasn't changed anything. I also tried installing gnome-shell to see if it was a problem with the lubuntu desktop, but it did not change anything.

Any suggestions would be gladly welcome.

Specs:

Lenovo W510
Nvidia 880M 
i7 Q720
4GB RAM

EDIT:

As @NikTh suggested, [this page] helped fix my initial issue. I simply ran the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

This got my display working properly, but now I load into a login screen, though, which I never had before. When I log in, the screen flashes and brings me right back to the same login screen.

Again, following @NikTh's suggestion, I ran:

```
rm ~/.Xauthority
sudo service lightdm stop ; sudo service lightdm start
```

And all is well again!

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/206289/95393) might help you to get your DE up and running again.

Comment: This definitely fixed it (mostly)! Now I load into a login screen, though, which I never had before. When I log in, the screen flashes and brings me right back to the same login screen (and the resolution is off - it's not 1900x1080p). Nonetheless, thank you so much for getting me this far! :)

Comment: Try to remove the file `~/.Xauthority` . Login from a TTY (CTRL+ALT+F2) and `rm ~/.Xauthority` . Be careful with the dot and the capital X. This file is hidden in your home directory. It is safe to remove it. It will be generated again in next login. After the deletion restart lightdm. `sudo service lightdm stop ; sudo service lightdm start`

Comment: If you don't mind, edit your question and add the problem with the login. I will convert my comments to an answer so we complete this. I mean Question and Answer (not comments only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely?lq=1) might help you to get your DE up and running again. It demonstrates on how you can uninstall the nvidia driver completely (clean up any leftovers..etc) and work with the nouveau driver (open source alternative).

**As for the [login problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/414713/how-to-fix-lubuntu-gui/415140#comment534834_414713)**

Try to remove the file `~/.Xauthority` . Login from a TTY (CTRL+ALT+F2) and

`rm ~/.Xauthority` .

Be careful with the dot and the capital X. This file is hidden in your home directory. It is safe to remove it. It will be generated again in next login. After the deletion restart lightdm.

`sudo service lightdm stop ; sudo service lightdm start`