# Low Screen Resolution

Tags: nvidia, xorg, resolution, xrandr

The max I can set my resolution currently is 1024x768, but my laptop's native resolution is 1920x1080. I've always been able to set it to 1920x1080 without issue, but since I broke my video driver (I installed 'nvidia-current' which broke my display, see [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/414713/how-to-fix-lubuntu-gui)) I haven't been able to get above the aforementioned 1024x768.

I've tried the instructions from [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8595940&mode=linear#post8595940) and [this wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution) but haven't made any progress.

Video Card:

```
travis@travis-ThinkPad-W510:~$ lscpi |grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT216GLM [Quadro FX 880M] (rev a2)
```

Output for 'xrandr'

```
travis@travis-ThinkPad-W510:~$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
    1024x768       61.0*
    800x600        61.0  
    848x480         0.0  
    640x480        60.0
```

Any suggestions?

Method used for trying to create '--newmode'

```
travis@travis-ThinkPad-W510:~$ cvt 1920 1080
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync     +vsync
travis@travis-ThinkPad-W510:~$ xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048     2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  19
  Current serial number in output stream:  19
```

Comment: I've just asked [a similar question on Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113512/) (which might get migrated here). But I'm already scared of what answer I might get - your question looks much more complex than my current level of competence could handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest NVIDIA GPUs, especially if designed to gaming (like my **GTX 750**), aren't supported by kernel.

You have to add an external ppa, install the graphic driver and reboot, so type in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mamarley/nvidia -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-346-uvm && sudo reboot
```

The maximum resolution will be automatically used since login screen.

---

PS I don't reccomend you to install Nvidia driver from the *Additional Driver* dialog (despite it should be easier), as you can choose only an older version (340.xx), the 346.xx one is not mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably removed the proprietary driver and your system is using generic VESA driver. Open **System Settings → Software Sources, tab Additional Drivers** and install the proprietary driver.