# Activating Nvidia Drivers

Tags: nvidia

When I use System Settings-Additional drivers- and try to activate;  NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernal module and VDPAU library,

I get this message; SystemError:Unable to correct problems,you have held broken packages.

Is there anyway to fix this?
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: Please open a terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) and issue these commands (one by one) `sudo apt-get update` & `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` & `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 vga` . What is the output ? Edit the OP and add the results.

Comment: 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation G71M [GeForce Go 7900 GS] [10de:0298] (rev a1) 
 Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:ff31] 
 Kernel driver in use: nvidia 
toshiba@toshiba-Satellite-P100:~$

Comment: Sorry pretty new at this, I hope this is what you needed.@NikTh

Answer (score 1):

Use [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/206289/95393) to completely remove nvidia drivers from your system.

Then, reboot the system and when you login to your Desktop Environment, open a terminal (open the terminal with CTRL+ALT+T) and issue the following commands (one by one - copy paste them from here to your terminal).

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-173 
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

If above procedure goes well, without errors, then reboot once more and it should be fine.

Comment: Hello,below is the message after sudo apt-get install nvidia-173.
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done 
E: Unable to locate package nvida-173 
toshiba@toshiba-Satellite-P100:~$ I did not enter in the last command because I'm unsure if I should after this E message?@NiKTh

Comment: Did you copy-paste the commands from here to your terminal one by one ? The package `nvidia-173` exists. [Look here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=nvidia-173&searchon=names&suite=precise&section=all), though the package `nvida-173` doesn't . Or maybe you must enable some repository ? Check from software center and enable canonical partners or/and independent [example image](http://imagebin.ubuntu-gr.org/1350544544.png)

Comment: Copied and pasted the commands one by one. Enabled updates on software centre.  OP of the 3 commands; toshiba@toshiba-Satellite-P100:~$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-173 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done 
nvidia-173 is already the newest version. 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 
toshiba@toshiba-Satellite-P100:~$ sudo nvidia-xconfig 
WARNING: Unable to locate/open X configuration file. 
New X configuration file written to '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' 
toshiba@toshiba-Satellite-P100:~$  @NikTh

Comment: And ? Same problem remains ? Reboot your system and see if the problem has resolved.

Comment: Rebooted system, same problem exists. Except that now nvidia_173, nvidia_304, nvidia_304_updates now show as being active but Nvidia binary Xorg, kernel module and VDPAU library will not activate. Still receive the broken packages message.@NikTh

Comment: Please don't use jockey (if you use this program). I know that this is only my opinion but I consider this program as a mess (it has completely removed from later Ubuntu versions). Can you open the nvidia settings ? Do you have any actual problem with your graphics ? If not, then you should be fine. Also, run these commands will help to determine if any other problem exist `sudo apt-get update` & `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`