# Problems with nvidia gt630m drivers

Tags: 12.04, unity, drivers, nvidia, graphics

Hello i have used Ubuntu 12.04 for some time now but now i have encountered a really annoying problem that drives me crazy. I  first got this problem when i updated my nvidia drivers, version 331 recomended. I also tried the none recomended version. The problem is that the xserver freezes, the computer itself is fine and the only problem is that "unity" freezes. The problem can be solved by simply do [ctrl+alt+(F1-F6)] and the [ctrl+alt+F7] in order to restart the xserver. Ubuntu works fine with "Unity2d" but the taskbar(The bar to the left) takes up way to much space. I posted this question some time ago but i gave up. I have reinstalled ubuntu but the problem remains.

Why does this happen?
How can i fix this problem?

Is it indeed the drivers that is the cause of this problem? or is it possible that it might be a graphic card failiure? Or any other reasons for this to happen?

How likely is it that the problem remains on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ( Since i am planning on an upgrade)

> > OS: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
>
> Computer Spec:
>
> > Asus K53SM
> >
> > Intel core i5 (2.5GHz)
> >
> > Nvidia GT 630m (2GB)
> >
> > 4gb ram

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried purging the nvidia package? See this post for a how to  [How can I uninstall a nvidia driver completely ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely)

If you cannot log into the desktop use Ctrl+Alt+F1  to access the terminal at the log in.

Comment: Ok i will see if this might work.

Comment: Ok it seems like this works, atleast this far. The only downside is that it seems like i have to use the integrated graphics from the CPU but thats not a big problem. If the problem doesnt come back untill tomorrow then this was really helpfull! =D. (So far i hope for the best but prepare for the worst)

Comment: Nothing worse than having a overly large paper weight in front of you. Please post back with results either way.

Comment: Begs the question, what are you using your system for? Casual gaming, productivity, surfing the net? If you absolutely have to have the nvidia card for 3D look here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA_Optimus

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I didnt solve the problem and it kept getting worse so i had to unstall ubuntu and use windows instead. Now when Ubuntu 14.04 has been released i am planning to try it and hopefully the problem is solved. Once again i apologize for the late reply and thanks for your help.