# Managing a laptop with dual graphics cards?

Tags: nvidia, intel-graphics

I understand this question has been asked before, but I'm still confused as to how it works and if I need to get anything else. Initially, this computer had been running Windows 7 and I had used it fine. I am now dual booting Ubuntu 13.10.

A few days ago I realized I shouldn't be running at the FPS I was running at due to having the Nvidia 630M and an Intel Family Graphics Card 3000. I had actually installed a Nvidia driver from the website and installed it, and my computer basically went corrupt. I had finally fixed it after ~2 1/2 hours and managed to get back in. Here I am, back to where I was, but I just installed Bumblebee to manage changing between the cards. I've installed nothing else relevant to changing graphics cards, or any other drivers. In my system details, my graphics is Intel Ivybridge Mobile.

I'm not sure if I have to run anything or if it runs automatically (IE; if I open Minecraft, will it use my Nvidia automatically?). I have looked at the tutorial and everything, but I just need some things clarified.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a 750m in my system, and with Ubuntu 14.04 and the proprietary drivers (Available by going to: System Settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers)

I can enable/disable the card when I want, and set up profiles for it.

Bumblebee is a headache and I never got it to work the way it was supposed to.

How attached are you to using 13.10 ? I say update to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Well, do I need to download a driver for the Nvidia? If so, what would be the safest way? because as I said in my post, downloading from the actual page and then installing basically made it so I couldn't login to the computer. It was terrible. I wouldn't MIND updating, not really attached, but I want to be able to use my Nvidia so I can run my games better. I also don't see any difference when I did $optirun java -jar Minecraft.jar as an example. Same FPS, no difference. Anyway I can actually tell if the Nvidia is working? edit: just checked that, I have no proprietary drivers in use.

Comment: 'lspci | grep VGA' Will tell you what GPU is in use. Looks like the newest proprietary drivers, that can be gotten the way I mentioned should support your card. If you tried what I said, and nvidia drivers do not show up there, you can try 14.04.

Comment: Depending on the mess that was made installing bumblebee and all that, you may have to install all of that to start fresh again.

`sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`

`sudo ppa-purge ppa:bumblebee/stable`

Comment: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)

Comment: That's what it said. I've never had any proprietary drivers for some reason. Ever since I got Ubuntu it's been running off of the Intel and even 2 days ago before I messed with Nvidia drivers, no proprietary drivers. Not sure what happened, but I do need help to get it in place / working. Also, no mess was made installing bumblee, went fine, just don't believe it's working.

Comment: Sorry also [http://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely] for uninstalling whatever nvidia stuff you have. Then try the proprietary, its always the recommended way.

Comment: So that response means your not using your nvidia GPU

Comment: So, what do I have to do now to get my Nvidia GPU working. From start to finish? I installed bumblee which included the Nvidia stuff. http://i.imgur.com/afhFx6s.png that is what shows with that. That's all I have that is related to drivers.

Comment: I suggest remove bumblebee, Plain and simple. This is a common problem, read more here [http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/installing-nvidia-drivers]

Comment: Alright. Now how'd I go about installing the correct proprietary driver for Nvidia 630M and will I need anything else for my computer to use that GPU correctly? edit: reading through that thing.

Comment: Well, I had uninstalled bumblebee, purged, got edgers, updated and upgraded, and not sure where to go from here. I need a proprietary driver and not sure how to go about getting it or if I just install the nvidia driver. I also reinstalled bumblebee as it had said.

Comment: Nothing shows up in System Settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers  ?  (in Software & Updates make sure Proprietary Drivers for Devices) is checked before going to the Additional Drivers page

Comment: Nothing shows. No proprietary devices, and yes, I have that ticked on the first tab.

Comment: try `optirun glxgears` and post results, if it works, your good to go.

Comment: garett@garett-700Z3C-700Z5C:~$ optirun glxgears
[  555.147607] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) intel(0): [drm] failed to set drm interface version: Permission denied [13].

[  555.147688] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.

Comment: That just happened. I assume this is the reason that all of this has happened. Any tips?

Comment: Still haven't fixed it. I had followed something to edit a file and add my BUSID, and it still gives me that error.

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2036010

and

http://mylinuxexplore.blogspot.ca/2014/03/solved-nvidia-cant-access-secondary-gpu.html