# Ubuntu 14.04 wont reboot after choosing nvidia drivers (optimus laptop)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-prime

Well I decided to give linux again a try. I was excited when I heard that ubuntu was supporting an alternative to bumblebee. But no luck today so far.

The installation goes flawless, I open the utility that install alternative drivers, nvidia 331, i think it is... then I reboot as requested and thats it. The system wont be able to reboot, it is stuck at the gnome symbol at the very begining of the booting proccess, I forgot to mention I use Ubuntu Gnome.

I have tried to install another choice that is listed, 331-updates, with the same luck

I have tried also installing using the terminal, same.
I would apreciate any help.

I would really like to know how to revert the drivers to nouveau,because every time I have to try... I am reinstalling the whole thing!!! it is kinda embarasing, and time comsuming! thanks folks!

Comment: This question has been asked before, and answered in [http://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely

Comment: The answer above still doesn't answer the users problem. I am having the same problem also.