# The system is running in low-graphics mode after bumblebee

Tags: nvidia, graphics

I tried to install bumblebee because of a HDMI problem. I ran these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia virtualgl linux-headers-generic
sudo reboot
```

Then I got `The system is running in low-graphics mode`, and I couldn't solve it.

Here are some outputs;

```
$ dpkg -l | egrep "nvidia|bumblebee"
rc nvidia-173
ii nvidia-304
rc nvidia-331
rc nvidia-331-updates
ii nvidia-common
ii nvidia-current
ii nvidia-persistenced
ii nvidia-prime
ii nvidia-settings
ii nvidia-settings-304
ii nvidia-settings-331
173.14.39-0ubuntu0.0.1
304.116-0ubuntu1^xedgers^precise1
331.20-0ubuntu0.0.2
331.38-0ubuntu0.0.1
1:0.2.44.2
304.116-0ubuntu1^xedgers^precise1
331.20-0ubuntu1^xedgers^precise1
0.5^hybrid0.0.3
331.20-0ubuntu0.0.3
331.20-0ubuntu0.0.3
331.20-0ubuntu1^xedgers^precise1
NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module annd VDPAU library
NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module annd VDPAU library
NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module annd VDPAU library
NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module annd VDPAU library
Findi obsolete NVIDIA drivers
Transitional package for nvidia-current
Load the NVIDIA kernel driver and create device files
Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
Tools for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
Transitional package for nvidia-settings
Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

---

```
$ sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nvidia-bug-report.log.gz
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'nvidia-bug-report.log.gz'
```

- 12.04 64bit
- Nvidia GT525M
- Dell Inspiron n5110

Comment: Try with ubuntu 14.04...I had similar problems with 12.04 but after installation of 14.04 I don't have any problems with my NVIDIA graphics cards!

Comment: Did you lose your personal documents ? If so, I can not do that

Comment: Actually I took backup on external hard disk and did a fresh install! It is recommended!

Comment: Also one more advice which may work..go to `/etc/X11` and rename `xorg.conf` file to `xorg.conf.backup` And reboot! This may help!

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by removing packages one by one

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-304
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-prime
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-common
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-settings
```

Answer (score 0):

Try purging bumblebee, at low-graphics screen go to tty1 by pressing ctrl+alt+F1 and login with your user name, password and run

> sudo apt-get purge bumblebee
>
> sudo apt-get purge bumblebee-nvidia

Comment: I've tried it. Problem still exists. There are no packages like that

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find your driver in the text consol by taping :

> sudo apt-cache search nvidia

Then locate your driver (maybe a mention to bumblebee in the name) and install it. After, you can reboot and enjoy :)

I tried it on my Ubuntu laptop and and it works well.

Good luck during your search.

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly a duplicate of a question about how to completely remove the nvidia drivers (and restore unit) [How can I uninstall a nvidia driver completely ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely)