# How to completely purge everything that is associated with nvidia?

Tags: nvidia, bumblebee

I have followed endless amount of guides in order to make primus work with steam in ubuntu 14.04 and yet nothing works. I would like to completely purge everything that is associated with nvidia, bumblebee, nvidia x server, primus, prime indicator and so on. Can I do so?

Comment: It also depends on how you installed these things.

Comment: @Panther Your comment raises a concern that the accepted answer below may not work all the time.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix This comment is from 2014 , but no the accepted answer will not work if one has manually installed the nvidia driver, it only works if it was installed with apt / apt-get. And what is `<any other packages>*` ?? . At any rate the answer worked for asdasda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions can help you here.

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia* bumblebee*  <any other packages>*
```

You could also open synaptic package manager, search for primus and mark it for complete removal.

Comment: I think this **might** be dangerous as it would remove `nvidia-common` which is a core of Ubuntu Desktop as this answer states: https://askubuntu.com/a/206289/307523