# dissapearing menu on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: launcher, icons

I recently switched to Ubuntu and after I installed my NVidia driver package by using  `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current` I relaunched my pc and everything seemed fine in the login screen but after I logged in the only thing I could was moving my mouse around on my background

I tried following the [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears) thread and I got to the `ccsm` menu and checked the Ubuntu unity plugin as described but my icons would not appear so I rebooted but I ended up with the same problem

I would appreciate if someone could find a solution to my problem.

Comment: What do you want?  Uninstall the driver and go back to the way it was or have an NVidia driver that works a bit better...  If the latter, what's your NVidia chipset?

Comment: i want to uninstall the driver and go back to the way it was before i installed it because it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

You should press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> which brings you to a black terminal screen.  Log in there with your normal user name and password.

Then you should follow this procedure: [How can I uninstall a nvidia driver completely ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely)

**:)**