# How to deal with being unable to boot Ubuntu distributions with a Nvidia discrete or hybrid graphics card

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia

This pertains to users whose systems have a Nvidia graphics card, dual Intel integrated graphics card (such as the Intel HD Graphics 5xx, 6xx, etc.).

When you boot, you can see GRUB options available but afterwards the system hangs, usually resulting in a black screen.

If you have 'quiet' removed from GRUB, you can see what the system is doing while booting. For Nvidia/Intel problems, it will print a message about software lockup or hang. For Ubuntu distros, holding ALT and PrtScr while typing reisub will safely reboot instead of having to hard shut down.

Answer (score 0):

**BIOS:** Configure settings to allow you to boot from a USB. Start your computer and enter BIOS setup from the splash screen. The key to enter it should be labeled on your BIOS splash screen. Common keys are F2, F10, ESC.

> - USB Virtualization: ON - This allows booting an operating system from.
> - Boot Mode: Legacy for MBR formatted USBs, UEFI for GPT formatted USBs.
> - Secure Boot: Applicable to EFI booting: You may need to disable Secure Boot due to unsigned kernels or non-free Nvidia drivers unless you've signed them yourself.

**First boot: getting into GRUB**: Some distributions boot into GRUB and allow you to edit options before booting in. For others, there are multiple variations of entering GRUB. I have come across pressing TAB, pressing ESC at the exact nano second, and a few others.

[image: GRUB]

**Editing GRUB**

Once there, press e to edit configuration.

[image: GRUB config]

There should be `quiet splash` located there, and right after it type `nouveau.modeset=0`, then it should boot fine. `quiet splash` was removed for visibility in the screenshot.

**Have `nouveau.modeset=0` enabled every boot**

Open terminal and type `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

[image: /etc/default/grub]

On the line beginning with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=`, add `nouveau.modeset=0` within the quotes. CTRL + O to save, enter, CTRL + X, then type `sudo update-grub` into terminal.

Other options that you can separately try in GRUB are:

```
nomodeset
i915.modeset=0
i915.modeset=1
```

References that I will read/integrate later:

> https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2340158
>
> [Is nomodeset still required?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747314/is-nomodeset-still-required)
>
> [What do the nomodeset, quiet and splash kernel parameters mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/716957/what-do-the-nomodeset-quiet-and-splash-kernel-parameters-mean)