# Login loop after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: login, compiz, lightdm

I encountered a login loop after updating xenial beta to the latest updates.

I tried a lot of things:

- `xauthority` or `/tmp` privileges change
- Reinstalling nvidia drivers, removing them.
- reinstalling `unity`, `unity-greeter`, `ubuntu-desktop`, `upstart`, `lightdm` and `compiz`.
- resetting `compiz` and `unity` settings.(I get `dbus` launch errors:

  ```
  Failed to commit changes to dconf: error spawning command line 'dbus-launch -auto launch=..................)
  ```
- using older kernel and failsafe (failsafe report no screen found)
- tried to launch other DE (steam big picture)

Here's xsession errors log:

```
unity:
open connection: connect: No such file or directory
Cannot connect to brltty at :0
upstart: gnome-session (unity) main process (5441) terminated with status 1
upstart unity-settings-daemon main process (5434) killed by TERM signal

steam big picture:
open connection: connect: No such file or directory
Cannot connect to brltty at :0
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmodeswitch_inhibitor.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file(: ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmodeswitch_inhibitor.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file(: ignored
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmodeswitch_inhibitor.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file(: ignored
Could not create GLX context
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libmodeswitch_inhibitor.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file(: ignored
```

In Unity (compiz) log there are a lot of errors about opengl plugin

```
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtenisonsString is NULL for screen 0
```

And a lot of plugins unloaded because of opengl.

Lightdm have sudden SIGTERM signal with no prior errors in the log.

xserver have 2 errors:

```
xf86EnablePorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
(EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)
```

But it continue through input operations until it suddenly get terminated.

Answer (score 18):

In my case original nvidia drivers was the cause and switching back to open source nouveau helped. First, I removed all stuff from nvidia:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge 'nvidia-*'
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
echo 'nouveau' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

(source: [How can I uninstall a nvidia driver completely ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely))

After that I could login, but unity didn't load, there was no launcher etc. It turn out I had to re-enable Unity plugin:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
DISPLAY=:0 ccsm
Find the Unity plugin and enable it.
```

(source: [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears))

Comment: The removal of `nvidia-*` was the main fix for me.  In `~/.xsession.errors` I had message `cannot connect to brltty at 0` which is related to NVIDIA.

Comment: I followed these exact steps but it did not work for me

Comment: Plus what if I need to use the Nvidia drivers, then this does not work.

Comment: @Hakaishinrare you able to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error on 16.04 as well. In my case it was also an NVidia driver issue. I have 8 monitors and I like how the NVidia diver performs with them. So to get it working, I:

1. Pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> at the login prompt and logged into through terminal.
2. Backed up may old `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file, as it was a pain to configure 8 monitors.
3. Downloaded the driver file from NVidia: `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.44.run`
4. Ran the following command: `sudo service lightdm stop` (driver install will fail if this step is skipped).
5. Reinstalled the driver: `sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.44.run` I was notified that the auto generated script did not complete and given the choice to continue the install which I accepted. I also chose to have the driver installed as a kernel module and have the program generate a new `xorg.conf` file (backed mine up before). At the end of the process it complained about a missing link to a lib, but gave instructions on linking to it. I put off dealing with that for later.
6. Rebooted and was able to login through the GUI.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that, when you update Ubuntu (and even when you install certain programs that call `/sbin/ldconfig`), there are changes made to `/etc/ls.so.cache`.

Try it and you'll see that the `ld.so.cache` file after such an installation/update will have a different size than before the operation.

This, in Ubuntu 16.04, results in a login loop when logging in from lightDM. Therefore, you should keep a copy of the original `ld.so.cache` since, with the new version generated after the installation/update, lightDM will no longer authenticate.

I have had this issue many times and have had to be very careful with this. I always keep a copy of the original file (`/etc/ld.so.cache.orig`) that lets me log in without the login loop and use that to log in. Then, once I have logged in successfully, I copy the new one (`/etc/ld.so.cache.new`) over. To do so, I have modified my `~/.bash_profile` file and have added this line:

```
sudo /bin/cp /etc/ld.so.cache.new /etc/ld.so.cache
```

Then, in order to copy the original file back when exiting the session so that I'll be ab;e to log ina gain next time, I have added this line to `/etc/gdm/PostSession/Default`:

```
/bin/cp /etc/ld.so.cache.orig /etc/ld.so.cache
```

For that to work, I have modified `/etc/sudoers` (by running `sudo vosudo`) to allow non privileged users to run the copy command:

```
ALL     ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/cp /etc/ld.so.cache.new /etc/ld.so.cache
```

This might look like an ugly hack, but it gets around this login-loop issue and, also, to keep the new `/etc/ld.so.cache` file.

Comment: Lo siento, pero el Ask Ubuntu es una pagina donde solo se escribe en Ingles. Gracias por la respuesta pero como es en Castellano, la tube que borrar. Si no hables, o no hables bien, el Ingles, puedes usar herramientas como el [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com) para traducir tus contribuciones.

Comment: De hecho, la traduje yo ya que tiene pinta de ser una solución buena.  Pero en el futuro, por favor pásala por Google Translate.

Answer (score 1):

I was using xfce and I manually checked each folder and file by renaming them. Deleting `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/displays.xml` worked for me.

I had nvidia drivers as well, but they were working fine when I logged in as root and a backup user.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this issue was caused by accidentially enabling Secure Boot in UEFI, which effects in third party drivers unusable (e.g. Nvidia). That caused X session error. After disabling Secure Boot, everything went back to normal.