# Ubuntu 16.04 stuck in login loop after attempting to install NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-375.39.run

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, login

I have tried answers from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/761581) but it has not worked for me.

.Xauthority is owned by myself.

.xsession-error shows:

```
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
upstart: gnome-session (Unity) main process(2743) terminated with status 1
upstart: unity-settings-daemon main process (2735) killed by TERM signal
upstart: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
upstart: upstart-dbus-session-fridge main process (2659) terminated with status 1
upstart: bamfdaemon main process (2644) killed by TERM signal
upstart: hud main process (2733) killed by TERM signal
upstart: unity7 prestart process(2737) terminated with status 143
upstart: logrotate main process (2540) killed by TERM signal
upstart: unity-panel-service main process (2750) killed by TERM signal
```

Can someone advice me how overcome the login loop problem so that I can gain access to my desktop.

**Update:** I found 3 interesting post. One strategy is to go all out to disable nouveau so that installation of NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-375.39.run can be done. [Eg1](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/907218/how-to-disable-nouveau-driver-to-install-nvidia-drivers-distribution-kali-linux-2-0/) and [Eg2](http://www.pimp-my-rig.com/2012/01/unload-nouveau-install-nvidia-driver.html). My issue looks identical to them. However, I was not able to execute the procedure described in by Eg2 (I used sudo instead of doing it as root). So I pursued a second strategy that is to install ubuntu repository Nvidia driver "without X/ in console" as described in [ubuntu help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia). I ran these commands:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
sudo apt-get --purge remove xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
sudo apt-get install nvidia-375
sudo service lightdm start
```

I was returned to my login window. I tried to login but am still unsuccessful. The login loop persists.

Update2: Just tried rebooting. During bootup, I get a popup window saying

> "The system is running in low=graphics mode. Your screen, graphics card, and input device setting could not be detected correctly. You will need to configure these yourself."

After clicking ok, I get another popup window that shows 4 options:

> What would you like to do?
>      Try running the default graphic mode.
>      Reconfigure graphics. 
>      Troubleshoot the error. 
>      Exit to console login.

However, the radiobuttons on the left of these options don't seem to work. I found out that these pop up windows are appearing in tty2 or Ctrl+Alt+F2.

Comment: You can uninstall it from console.

Comment: @Pilot6 My installation had problem and was aborted. Thereafter I had this problem. Can u advice me what and how to uninstall? the installation also tried to blacklist nouveau and tried to reinstalled but that failed too.

Comment: Enter console by Ctrl+Alt+F1 and run the same file with `--uninstall`. It was initially a bad idea to install drivers this way.

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks. Tried reinstalling. Even after blacklisting nouveau, Nvidia installation log says nouveau could still be included in system initial ramdisk or x configuration file, thus failed and I am still stuck in the login loop. I tried rebooting and reinstallation. What should I do next?

Comment: I can't get what are you doing. Uninstall the driver, unblacklist nouveau and install the driver a normal way using a repository.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have no Nvidia driver installed and the blacklist removed. I am still stuck in the login loop.