# Problems after upgrading to 16.04 from 15.10

Tags: 16.04, drivers, upgrade, radeon, amd-graphics

I upgraded from 15.10 to 16.04 through the distribution upgrade utility. At the end it said upgrade successful with some errors. 
I rebooted and I couldn't login at all. It was a login loop problem but I could solve it using this (https://askubuntu.com/a/761581/666490).

Now after I logged in, I was struck by the terrible resolution (1024x768). So I guessed maybe I need to install fglrx (I have AMD Radeon R5 not NVIDIA). That's when I knew it is not supported on 16.04 anymore. 
And the Radeon open-source driver is already pre-installed with 16.04 but it doesn't seem to be.

The resolution is terrible and I cannot increase it from System Settings.

What should I do?

Comment: Is this relevant, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1552693 ?

Comment: Thank you for the link @J.J.Hakala but the problem was actually solved. So, I installed the AMD GPU Pro driver which solved the problem but got me back to the login loop problem. I used the recovery console to remove the driver using sudo amdgpu-pro-uninstall and when I rebooted, I could login and have the old driver working with all the resolutions I should have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I installed the AMD GPU Pro driver which solved the problem but got me back to the login loop problem. I used the recovery console to remove the driver using `sudo amdgpu-pro-uninstall` and when I rebooted, I could login and have the old driver working with all the resolutions I should have.