# Latest NVIDIA driver on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and I notice that in the "Additional Drivers" tab of "Software & Updates", the latest versions of NVIDIA drivers I can install are

1. version 367.57 from nvidia-367 (proprietary)
2. version 370.28 from nvidia-370 (open source)

Aside from the fact that I don't know what "proprietary" and "open source" mean here, I also don't see an option to select the driver version based on my actual graphics card. I'm using GTX 1080 and the current Long Lived Branch version is 375.20; will the Ubuntu graphics PPA be updated eventually, or will I have to manually install 375?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I cant find any reference to support in `jockey` for nVidia 375 yet.  But the manual installation isn't as difficult as you might think.

**Official Instructions**

1. Download the driver version 375.20 from [here](http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/111596)
2. `$ chmod 777 NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-375.20.run`
3. `$ sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-375.20.run`
4. `$ sudo apt-get update`
5. `$ sudo apt-get upgrade`

**Install via PPA**

1. `$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`
2. `$ sudo apt update`

**Potential Issues**

- Black screen on startup - Add nomodeset to grub - [see this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu)
- Removing nVidia Drivers - Purge - [see this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely)

**Addendum to the Login Loop issue, via @michael__treat :**

Make sure that secure boot is disabled in Windows Boot Manager. The walk-through from Ubuntu may be incomplete. During testing, I found that I had to use the Windows System Boot Manager, and manually disable secure boot.

This solved the login loop issue in my case.

*TL;DR: Make sure secure boot is actually turned off.*

- When you reach grub, go to windows boot manager
- Press <kbd>e</kbd>
- change secureboot from `enabled` to `disabled`

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for me. I have to go to TTY, disable `mdlight`, disable nouveau (almost bricking the GUI) and still can't get this to work.

Comment: I used the official instructions described here with the 384.111 and it got me to the login loop. I don't have windows on this computer. Help someone?

Comment: @embe, according to a comment here: https://lenovolinux.blogspot.ca/2016/05/bumblebee-on-lenovo-t440p-nvidia-gt.html

"You will have to enter recovery mode after the first reboot because there will be a login loop. I couldn't ctrl-alt f1 to a tty... After continuing the steps it worked for me."

Although that was for installing Bumblebee but I thought it might be relevant :)

Comment: Everyone use the PPA solution. Less chances of messing up your system.

Answer (score 9):

```
Proprietary : Owned/Provided by some company (In your case these are the 
              Graphics drivers provided by Nvidia)

Open Source: Developed/Provided by an open source community.
```

If you want to use `CUDA` (nVidia's stuff for executing functions on the GPU), you should use the proprietary driver.

If you want to use `OpenCL` (something like CUDA, developed by Khronos), you have to use the open source driver.

To install latest drivers add `PPA` :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
```

Now, find `Software & Updates` under `System Settings` and select the required driver version form the `Additional Drivers` tab, select the driver and click `Apply Changes`. Restart and Enjoy!

PS: Sometimes the best driver version doesn't seem to work well, so you must check whether you're enjoying all the functionalities provided and whether it contain bugs and please do check whether `nvidia-prime` is installed because it comes handy in most of the situations where bugs lead to a black screen.

Comment: TRust me just do theese with no "" and nothing else

"sudo apt-get update"       

"sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall"

Comment: @MeganFoxz: Thanks. "sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall" worked like a charm. I upgraded my hardware from an older NVIDIA card to a newer one.

Answer (score 1):

I was successful updating Asus NVIDIA 1080 8 GB GPU drivers for Ubuntu 16.04 with the CUDA Toolkit:

```
$ wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb
$ wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/libcudnn6_6.0.21-1%2Bcuda8.0_amd64.deb
$ wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/libcudnn6-dev_6.0.21-1%2Bcuda8.0_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i libcudnn6_6.0.21-1+cuda8.0_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i libcudnn6-dev_6.0.21-1+cuda8.0_amd64.deb
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install cuda=8.0.61-1
$ sudo apt-get install libcudnn6-dev
```

Reboot then proceed with the following:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-367
$ sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev
$ sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev
```

I lifted the aforementioned from [Changjiang's blog](https://yangcha.github.io/GTX-1080/), which primes your build for Deep Learning if you're so inclined.. :D

Answer (score 0):

$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
$ sudo apt update

This is the best solution.Do this and update the nvidia driver and it works with 4.13 kernels
Nvidia 340.104 works with kernel 4.13 without problems. I tested it on Peppermint 8 respin

Comment: The question was about the latest driver, which at the time was 375. 340 obviously isn't the latest driver. Also, that it works on Peppermint 8 doesn't tell whether it works on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I found it more convenient to use the proprietary drivers. The next question is, which version? There is a systematic approach to installing the most appropriate driver, which may or not may be the latest version. I wrote the annotated installation guide in [this article](http://tech.amikelive.com/node-731/how-to-properly-install-nvidia-graphics-driver-on-ubuntu-16-04/). The steps in brief are as follows.

1. Go to [NVIDIA driver download page](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us).
2. Provide the OS information, graphics card model, and CUDA toolkit version and perform Search.
3. In the search result page, the recommended driver version will be displayed. Keep it as a reference.
4. After adding the private NVIDIA ppa repository, update the apt index.

   $ sudo apt-get update
5. Search the available drivers from the apt cache

   $ sudo apt-cache search nvidia | grep -E "nvidia-[0-9]{3}"
6. From the list, install the version recommended by NVIDIA (may not be the latest). For version 390, the install command will be as simple as:

   $ sudo apt-get install nvidia-390
7. Reboot the system and check the driver version with nvidia-smi command