# Very high CPU usage in Firefox when watching YouTube on 17.10

Tags: firefox, video, cpu, youtube

So I noticed that the fans of my Dell XPS 9560 kick in whenever I'm watching YouTube. I looked at CPU usage with top and powertop and 'Web Content' uses 50-90% of CPU. I googled a ton and it appears that Firefox just does not use hardware acceleration on Linux. So I followed every guide out there, changed every about:config line that is spoken of but the CPU usage is still the same. This is really annoying to me as I watch a lot of YT and my laptop is pretty powerful so this should not be the case. I tried both the Intel and Nvidia GPU but that is not the issue. Has somebody here found a solution?

I really searched all of AU and google but none of the solutions so far work.

Specs:

- Intel i7-7700HQ
- 16 GB DDR4 -2400MHz

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried installing the latest Nvidia drivers? https://askubuntu.com/questions/851069/latest-nvidia-driver-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: I have not, but I use prime to select between GPU's, and I am only using the Intel GPU for the moment. I believe I have 390 installed. But when I googled the issue it was pretty clear that browsers somehow have a problem with hardware acceleration on Linux...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this: https://www.pcsuggest.com/chromium-hardware-accelerated-video-decoding-linux/

it appears to work, CPU usage is very low with this ppa. But the downside is the process of installing the API's. I went through every step on this page: https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/ubuntu/chromium-beta

but it still does not work. I am done for today, maybe I'll try to figure out why it does not work later.

EDIT: simply rebooting worked!!

EDIT2: but the CPU usage is high again :(

FINAL EDIT: You have to enable gpu blacklist flag, and then everything works :)

Comment: The question is about Firefox.

Answer (score 5):

Same here, Firefox eats a lot of CPU(>100%) when playing Youtube videos. One tweak is to enter `about:config` in address bar, then search for below flag and make it `true`.

> media.hardware-video-decoding.force-enabled

After that, the cpu usages becomes *20-40%* which is kind of normal and on par with *Chromium*.

You could possibly get more juice after using [this h264ify addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/h264ify/).

Comment: This reduced my CPU usage from around 50% to 20%.