# How to find correct driver for updating NVIDIA on Ubuntu16.04 LTS?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I am following the instructions in [How to install the latest Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus) to update the NVIDIA drivers, and `lspci -vnn | grep VGA` outputs:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1b06] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1b80] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

From [PCI Device 10de:1b06](https://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PC/10de/1b06) and [PCI Device 10de:1b80](https://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PC/10de/1b80), I think I need GeForce GTX 1080 and GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, both of which I cannot find at [the driver download page](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx#)

Comment: Please try check in "Additional Drivers" tab of "Software & Updates" and tell if you get any detail there.

Comment: @Ajay it shows NVIDIA corporation: Unknown, `this device is using a manually installed driver`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download all required Ubuntu drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543325/how-to-download-all-required-ubuntu-drivers)

Answer (score 1):

## Ubuntu 16.04

Ubuntu 16.04 has less drivers available than 18.04.

With a [quick search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=nvidia&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all) at https://packages.ubuntu.com/. I found that the latest driver available was **nvidia-384**.

Using the official LTS packages, **nvidia-384** is the newest driver you can install.

However, driver **440** is available at https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/results/159360/ (Apr 07, 2020).

[image]

This download is not a package but an installer that will verify your system for compatible drivers and should install the latest version.

The installer is run through the terminal.

**Note**: You may need to change the file permissions with `chmod u+x filename' and then execute.

## Ubuntu 18.04

As ubuntu 18.04 already has updated drivers I offer a
GUI and terminal installation:

### Option 1: Graphical User Interface (GUI) method

Get to the so called **Additional Drivers** window. This is a tab inside an application called **Software and Updates**. Bellow example on how it should look like.

**Note**: I recommend selecting the latest **nvidia-driver-440** (as of May 30, 2020 for ubuntu 18.04) unless you have specific need for a different version. I am using an SDK that requires the use of proprietary driver 435.

[image: Additional Drivers]

### Option 2: Bash Terminal

In a new terminal window, find current available drivers with command

```
apt-cache search nvidia-driver
```

[image: Nvidia Drivers Found]

Only worry about the drivers that begin with **nvidia-driver**. In the example about the newest driver would be **nvidia-driver-440**.

Install the driver (will require *root* privileges) `sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-###`. **Replace** *###* with the respective number found in your search *440* for my example.

### Reboot computer

The computer should require a reboot let the video driver changes take effect.

Comment: I downloaded the installer and ran it, which gave me the `exit X server` error. I'm trying follow steps in here https://askubuntu.com/questions/149206/how-to-install-nvidia-run . I tried ctrl+alt+f1 but that takes me to black screen with 5 dots on it and just stays stuck there. Any clue?

Comment: I was able to log in to tty1 once and then came this error https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/62, so I thought I'll do the steps again and since then again ctrl+alt+f1 but that takes me to black screen with 5 dots on it and just stays stuck there.

Comment: I must say its much easier now to upgrade Nvidia drivers ... a few years ago you used to have to kill the X server and run all the purge old commands from the console since a normal terminal window would not be available after killing X ... then from the console issue the install new nvidia drivers commands including `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`  ... its SO much easier now ... long live change

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/851069/latest-nvidia-driver-on-ubuntu-16-04) is the answer for your query.

```
Proprietary : Owned/Provided by some company (In your case these are the 
              Graphics drivers provided by Nvidia)

Open Source: Developed/Provided by an open source community.
```

If you want to use `CUDA` (nVidia's stuff for executing functions on the GPU), you should use the proprietary driver.

If you want to use `OpenCL` (something like CUDA, developed by Khronos), you have to use the open source driver.

To install latest drivers add `PPA` :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
```

Now, find `Software & Updates` under `System Settings` and select the required driver version form the `Additional Drivers` tab, select the driver and click `Apply Changes`. Restart and Enjoy!

PS: Sometimes the best driver version doesn't seem to work well, so you must check whether you're enjoying all the functionalities provided and whether it contain bugs and please do check whether `nvidia-prime` is installed because it comes handy in most of the situations where bugs lead to a black screen.

**Additionally** In above post [MeganFoxz](https://askubuntu.com/users/687447/meganfoxz) suggested only and just to run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Comment: I have a proxy server because of which I mostly can't install via apt-repository. `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` fails too with error returned by /usr/bin/dpkg