# When I try to install Nvidia driver 440 using repo/ppa , driver 440 is not present after adding that repo

Tags: nvidia, ubuntu-drivers

I followed these steps to install nvidia driver 440 in ubuntu system of version 16.04. My graphics card model is nvidia **GeForce GTX 1080**

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`

`sudo apt-get update`

When I do `ubuntu-drivers devices`

It shows like

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
manual_install: True
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001B80sv000010DEsd0000119Ebc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
driver   : nvidia-430 - third-party free recommended
driver   : nvidia-415 - third-party free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
driver   : nvidia-418 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-410 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-384 - distro non-free
```

In the above output the driver 440 is not present.

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-440`

The output of the above line is

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package nvidia-440 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'nvidia-440' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Did you look at what that PPA provides for xenial; I don't see any 440 available - https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=xenial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Egraphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) you can see that 440 is not available for 16.04

```
sudo apt install nvidia-graphics-drivers-430
```

This is the latest version on 16.04 on the PPA, to get 440 you need to upgrade to a newer release, 18.04 or 20.04 both have a package for 440 and are LTS releases.

You can get a 440 binary from [Nvidia](https://www.nvidia.co.uk/Download/driverResults.aspx/160191/en-uk) and try to install that using [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/851069/latest-nvidia-driver-on-ubuntu-16-04) but it is not ideal as there are no automatic updates and you would need to install it for every update.