# Nvidia laptop - External monitor not working when prime power saving mode enabled

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, power-management, battery, nvidia-prime

I have the following laptop.

[image: System info]

I am trying to use an external monitor with Nvidia Prime settings set to power save

[image]

But it works only in performance mode.

I have tried to [follow this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1134579/834728) but doesn't work for me.

it's possible to use it this way? or there is a way to use the performance mode but reduce the battery usage? my battery last 3x more using power saving.

I am using `lightdm`

EDIT: for now, i'm using an gnome extension to fast switch PRIME profile and rebooting, but would be great if it works...