# how to connect a TV to ubuntu 20.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, 20.04

can you help me to hook up a television to my computer via xrandr, I have tried to use the command xrandr --output HDMI-1 --auto --right-of eDP-1 and it did nothing, the output of xrandr -q is:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
```

eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080     60.06*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93    40.04
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88
   1600x1024     60.17
   1400x1050     59.98
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82
   1280x1024     60.02
   1440x900      59.89
   1400x900      59.96    59.88
   1280x960      60.00
   1440x810      60.00    59.97
   1368x768      59.88    59.85
   1360x768      59.80    59.96
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91
   1152x864      60.00
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74
   1024x768      60.04    60.00
   960x720       60.00
   928x696       60.05
   896x672       60.01
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82
   960x600       59.93    60.00
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25
   840x525       60.01    59.88
   864x486       59.92    59.57
   800x512       60.17
   700x525       59.98
   800x450       59.95    59.82
   640x512       60.02
   720x450       59.89
   700x450       59.96    59.88
   640x480       60.00    59.94
   720x405       59.51    58.99
   684x384       59.88    59.85
   680x384       59.80    59.96
   640x400       59.88    59.98
   576x432       60.06
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32
   512x384       60.00
   512x288       60.00    59.92
   480x270       59.63    59.82
   400x300       60.32    56.34
   432x243       59.92    59.57
   320x240       60.05
   360x202       59.51    59.13
   320x180       59.84    59.32
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

Comment: Could you give us more details, such as the desktop environment (Gnome, KDE, etc.) that you are running? Also, what graphics card do you have? On the TV, when you plug something else into that HDMI port of the TV does it show something (if you have Windows installed as well, you could try booting into that)? Currently it's showing that the HDMI cable connection is not detected. Also, I am assuming you are running this on a laptop.

Comment: the environment is gnome, my graphics card is Nvidia 1050ti, and the tv pairing worked on windows os, and yes I am running on a laptop! thank you for the quick reply!

Comment: Ok. Do you have the nvidia proprietary drivers installed? https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers

Comment: yes, i performed the install instructions and the terminal stated that I have the latest version

Comment: Can you try this solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/1134579/907907

Comment: It works! the screen shows up but I can't get any audio to work with my video?

Comment: nvm, I got the audio working! thank you for your help!

Comment: Sounds like the right candidate for a new question! Anyways, have a go at this and see if it answers your question: https://itsfoss.com/how-to-fix-no-sound-through-hdmi-in-external-monitor-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Oh good. Glad it worked!