# Ubuntu 20.04 primary display not recognized Nvidia graphics

Tags: nvidia, 20.04

I have tried everything I can and have gotten no results, can someone help please! I have set up auto login but to no avail
Edit: I tried hooking up a secondary display and it worked but it is being treated as the primary display and my laptop monitor is not detected

Answer (score 0):

Update, I fixed the issue via switching to the light dm display manager, and installing the PPA version of the Nvidia graphics driver, then following this tutorial: [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1134579/907907)