# HDMI port not working with Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, hdmi, msi, portable

I have a MSI Laptop running on windows 10 and a plug and play Ubuntu 20.04 on a Samsung Portable SSD T5

When using Ubuntu, I am trying to use a second monitor via HDMI however nothing happens when I connect it.

I am new to Linux, What should I do?

Note: When I am using Windows, the HDMI port is working as expected

Comment: Ubuntu might not support your GPU out of the box. Could you open a terminal and execute `inxi -G`? Copy the output from the terminal into your question (use the [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1394283/edit) link)

Comment: @kanehekili From the self-answer it seems like Ubuntu 20.04 does support the MSI laptop's GPU, but it does not support it out of the box however the proprietary graphics drivers can be installed by running `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't recognize the self-answer. So I'll assume its a nvidia GPU

Comment: In my case, sometimes it works after rebooting, other time after connecting other display and then - back my primary monitor. Time to time, nothing helps at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if you have the latest drivers

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Then check for your additional drivers. Try to go to

- Software & updates
- reboot

This resolved my issue, I think because ubuntu did not recognize drivers because of some updates.

Inspired from this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1276794/1573261

Comment: Please note that `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` is deprecated. Running `ubuntu-drivers -h` returns some output containing the message
"Deprecated, please use 'install' instead"

Comment: My output, for Ubuntu 23, is: `All the available drivers are already installed.` and that didn't resolve my problem. HDMI suddenly not working after standby laptop (which I did several times until today)

Comment: Similar to RobyB except my message was No drivers installed.

Answer (score 2):

I've been through this problem for a few months.
I tried all almost all answers in google and still could not solve it

[Solved]
turns out that disabling secure boot in bios fixed the problem
*please learn about secure boot before disabling it

Answer (score 1):

When I updated to Ubuntu 22.04 I started getting ACPI errors and my HDMI port no longer was working on my newer Samsung laptop. The following hid the ACPI errors and curiously fixed my HDMI output.
This was found on linux.org related only to ACPI errors but it worked for the HDMI issue too. I cannot explain why it worked but the errors occurred the same time my HDMI port stopped working.

1. `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
2. edit line with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and add `loglevel=3`, it should look like `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='quiet splash loglevel=3'`
3. `sudo update-grub related`
4. reboot

When I did this everything worked again, hope this helps someone it has been a frustrating problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, one process was blocking `~/.config/monitors.xml` file, so it was not writable. Only fresh monitors were working fine, old ones were ignored. I removed that file to reset all settings. Now the `HDMI` port works fluently with my displays.

**My setup**

- Ubuntu 23.10
- Gnome 45.2
- Dell Precision 7520
- Intel HD 630
- Nvidia Quadro M2200