# Press ctrl+c to cancel all filesystem checks in progress appears after connecting external monitor

Tags: grub2, external-monitor, ubuntu-drivers

A few weeks back, the company I worked for bought an external monitor for me to connect my computer in. The laptop in question has the Ubuntu version 20.04 and it is a HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop.

Since the external monitor was not being recognized I followed a tutorial where I changed the driver's computer momentarily to a previous version and then changed it back to the most recent driver.

This seemed to do the trick since the laptop started recognizing the external monitor.

The problem is that after this, the laptop always starts up with the "Press ctrl+c to cancel all filesystem checks in progress" message on screen unless I connect the external monitor first.

What suggestions do you have to solve this issue?
Thank you for your responses in advance!

Comment: Are you cancelling the checks? They usually run because the file system isn't in order, which usually means it wasn't shutdown correctly. Are you letting the machine shutdown fully before closing the lid? What was there tutorial? Can you post your dmesg file?

Comment: Hello there! Thank you for your comment!

1. The first few times I tried cancelling the checks because it was taking too long (more than 5 - 10 minutes) but the laptop wouldn't respond so I manually restarted the laptop and then bypassed the checks by pressing a few specific keyboards (I don't remember right now what they were).

2. Here is the instructions I followed: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246654/ubuntu-20-04-second-monitor-on-hdmi-port-not-detected

3. Yes, I always make sure that the computer has fully shutdown fully before closing the lid