# Second monitor can't be detected, suddenly despite drivers updates

Tags: drivers, graphics, 22.04, multiple-monitors

I used to plug in through HDMI a monitor to my laptop. Today it refuses to work, the monitors says no signal from the source. I updated the Nvidia drivers, I have a Quadro M600M.

I tried all the solutions found here
[Second monitor suddenly can't be detected (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277720/second-monitor-suddenly-cant-be-detected-ubuntu-20-04-1-lts)

but nothing works. I am on Ubuntu 22.04. An interesting fact: when I go into Settings, about, for Graphics I read Mesa Intel® HD Graphics P530 (SKL GT2). I never paid attention at this before, but shouldn't it be my nvidia GPU?

Please help ... I really need this second monitor :( my laptop is quite old, 6 years. I am worried my GPU is damaged or something.

Thanks everyone