# external monitor, nvidia-smi and maybe Nvidia drivers not working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, external-monitor

I would like to use either a Dell P2417H or a Dell P2414Hb external monitor on my Ubuntu 20.04 laptop. Neither seem to work, though. I had a look at this question

[External Monitor not working. Ubuntu, nvidia](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105332/external-monitor-not-working-ubuntu-nvidia)

and I tried to fix my NVIDIA drivers. The solutions proposed there don't work, though. First of all, I tried

```
nvidia-smi
```

to check my driver version. I got the error

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

I tried also

```
nvidia-settings -q NvidiaDriverVersion
```

which is mentioned [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25663/how-to-get-the-version-of-my-nvidia-driver) and I got the error(s)

```
ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded


ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system



ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded


ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system
```

Finally, I tried to install the drivers recommended by Ubuntu with

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

But I keep getting the same error messages. *and* I'm still unable to use either of my external monitors. Any tips?

EDIT; my laptop is a HP Omen 15-ax000nl, and the video card seems to be a GeForce GTX 965M:

```
$ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001427sv0000103Csd00008257bc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GM206M [GeForce GTX 965M]
driver   : nvidia-driver-418-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-450 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-460-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-460 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

About Secure Boot, I'm not sure what it is, but if it's what I think it is, then it's not disabled, nor I have any idea how to disable it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NVIDIA drivers are not signed so they will not work with Secure Boot, so first disable Secure Boot in the BIOS settings.

Since the NVIDIA drivers are already installed, the driver should be working after a reboot.  If they are not, make sure you have the proper NVIDIA driver installed.  The 965M can use the newest drivers from NVIDIA so the NVIDIA 460 driver will work fine.

You can check which of your GPUs is the current active one using `prime-select`.

`prime-select query` will show you the current active GPU.

`prime-select nvidia` will activate the NVIDIA GPU (if applicable).

`prime-select intel` will activate the Intel GPU (if applicable).