# Unable to add external monitor Dell P2417H to Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: dell, intel, xps, external-monitor, 23.10

Firstly I've searched and found nothing that works for me, in particular here: [external monitor, nvidia-smi and maybe Nvidia drivers not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1323741/external-monitor-nvidia-smi-and-maybe-nvidia-drivers-not-working)

I'm running a dell XPS with Intel® Graphics (RPL-P) and Wayland, changing this to x11 didn't work either.

I've also tried solution from here, which i suspect may work but I don't have the additional drivers show up [Ubuntu 22.04 External monitor not detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1451002/ubuntu-22-04-external-monitor-not-detected)

Graphics card:

```
    darylls@XPS-Ubuntu:~$ lspci -v | grep VGA -A2
    00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-P [Iris Xe Graphics] (rev 04) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Dell Raptor Lake-P [Iris Xe Graphics]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 200, IOMMU group 1
```

This is what nvidia looks like for me:

```
darylls@XPS-Ubuntu:~$ nvidia-smi
Command 'nvidia-smi' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-470         # version 470.223.02-0ubuntu0.23.10.1, or
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-470-server  # version 470.223.02-0ubuntu0.23.10.1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-525         # version 525.147.05-0ubuntu0.23.10.1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-525-server  # version 525.147.05-0ubuntu0.23.10.1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-535         # version 535.129.03-0ubuntu0.23.10.1
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-535-server  # version 535.129.03-0ubuntu0.23.10.1
```

I've tried all 3 listed here, 470, 525, 535 all fail, but if my graphics card is a RPL-P am I looking in the wrong direction here?

Finally my Acer display xrandr:

```
darylls@XPS-Ubuntu:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-2 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 700mm x 390mm
   3840x2160     29.98*+
```

I've disable secure boot, tried x11 and replaced the obvious leads etc, monitor works with windows laptop so I'm confident this is a Ubuntu driver issue.

Thanks.