# Laptop HDMI output randomly stopped working

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I use an old Dell laptop from 2011 as my secondary machine at home.  It's always hooked up via HDMI to a monitor.  I've had no problems at all with it until now.  I booted up this evening and it just doesn't detect the monitor over HDMI at all anymore.  I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the Nvidia drivers but this didn't help.  When I open up the "Nvidia xserver settings" it just has a blank application with no options anymore.  How can I check to see if this is a software or hardware issue at this point?  I am quite new to ubuntu and don't know my way too well around the terminal, so I'll need detailed instructions if anyone can help me diagnose what's wrong with my system.

Using grub to boot back one version of the linux version does get the Nvidia xserver application working again, but I still cant detect my monitor.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: Can you add details about your system? E.g. laptop model, video card model, Ubuntu version?

Comment: It's a Dell Inspiron 17R from 2011 IIRC.  The Graphics card is an Nvidia Geforce Go 525M 
I'm using Ubunto 20.10.

Something else I have noticed is in the "about" section of my computer, the Nvidia card is not listed and instead its just "Intel® HD Graphics 3000 (SNB GT2)"

Comment: Update:
I tried this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1134579/1192904 
Which didn't seem to change anything.  However, now if I boot into " Ubuntu Linux 5.8.0.44" Instead of "Ubuntu Linux 5.8.0.45 my monitor works just fine. 
So apparently something in a recent update broke my Nvidia drivers I'm guessing. At least I know its not a hardware issue, and it's software.  I just have no idea how to fix it for the more recent version.

Comment: I've had a similar problem, my fix was as follows. From Settings -> About -> Software Updates, go to "Additional Drivers". Then choose an alternative driver and restart the computer. In my case, it was likely a software update that changed my driver to a non-working one and I had to manually change it back.