# Second monitor not working via USB-C

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, xrandr, usb-c

When I search online, I saw a couple of similar issues but most of them are with Dock station. I am not using a dock, I am using HDMI to USB-C cable. HDMI part connects to the external monitor and USB-C connects to my laptop (Thinkpad X1 Extreme Gen 2).
The cable works with Windows OS with no issue but does not work with Ubuntu.
Monitor works with HDMI to HDMI cable, so monitor works.

I got output using `journalctl -b` and here is the output when I plug in USB-C;

```
Mar 31 22:38:11 aydin kernel: usb 1-7: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
Mar 31 22:38:11 aydin kernel: usb 1-7: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
Mar 31 22:38:11 aydin kernel: usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=25a4, idProduct=9311, bcdDevice= 2.01
Mar 31 22:38:11 aydin kernel: usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Mar 31 22:38:11 aydin kernel: usb 1-7: Product: USB C Video Adaptor      
Mar 31 22:38:11 aydin kernel: usb 1-7: Manufacturer: USB C  
Mar 31 22:38:11 aydin kernel: usb 1-7: SerialNumber: 000000000001
Mar 31 22:38:11 aydin mtp-probe[32822]: checking bus 1, device 9: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7"
Mar 31 22:38:11 aydin mtp-probe[32822]: bus: 1, device: 9 was not an MTP device
Mar 31 22:38:11 aydin mtp-probe[32829]: checking bus 1, device 9: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7"
Mar 31 22:38:11 aydin mtp-probe[32829]: bus: 1, device: 9 was not an MTP device
Mar 31 22:38:15 aydin kernel: ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: UCSI_GET_PDOS returned 0 bytes
```

And my `xrand` output:

```
DVI-I-5-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-4-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-3-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-2-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
eDP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080     60.01 +  60.01*   59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00
```

And, `lshw -C display` output is;

```
 *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:166 memory:ed000000-edffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:ee080000-ee0fffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:167 memory:6040000000-6040ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

And lastly, `lsusb` output is;

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 06cb:00bd Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b67d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 25a4:9311 USB C   USB C Video Adaptor      
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1532:005c Razer USA, Ltd Razer DeathAdder Elite
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

As you can see
`Bus 001 Device 009: ID 25a4:9311 USB C   USB C Video Adaptor`
Ubuntu recognizes USB as Video Adaptor (I guess) but I can not see it at xrandr. Is it possible to add USB-C to xrandr?
What the problem can be?
Probably I will not find an answer but I just wanted to give it a shot :)

Comment: Please don't put SOLVED in the title of your question - https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [External Monitor not working. Ubuntu, nvidia](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105332/external-monitor-not-working-ubuntu-nvidia). I'm glad you were able to find an answer to your question. It's probably better that we close this one as a [duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/help/duplicates) so the answer is easier to find for future visitors.

Comment: I'm sorry, I m new at this. I'm learning :) Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I finally found a solution
https://askubuntu.com/a/1134579/1185670

As "thomasbangels" mentioned at that post, edit the line with nano;

`sudo nano /lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-kms.conf`

and comment

```
# This file was generated by nvidia-prime
# Set value to 0 to disable modesetting
# options nvidia-drm modeset=1
```

Then change `sudo prime-select nvidia` solved the problem.

Comment: Ubuntu 22: I did this suggestion, but then I couldn't change the display layout in the settings. I undid this suggestion and then everything went back to normal lol. Everything works now.