# Only Top Left Quarter of Screen Showing Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: multiple-monitors, xorg, display, display-resolution, xrandr

As title says only the top left quarter of my primary monitor works. The other two monitors work as expected. My set up as been working for a long time and only started doing this after a reboot - I don't recall if I installed any particular updates or software.

Some weird related behavior:

- The rest of the screen still functions I just can't see what's on it (e.g. if I know where a button is in the black part of the screen I can still click on it)
- If I try to change the display settings and e.g. make a different display my primary display, the displays flash on and off as usual to indicate a settings change but the setting does not actually change
- The behavior still occurs on a fresh live USB of Ubuntu 22.04
- The behavior does not occur on Ubuntu on Wayland or if I boot into windows (i.e. not a hardware problem)
- A screenshot shows the whole screen working (otherwise I would post a screenshot)
- If I only plug in the problematic monitor, it works as expected - no issues, I only get the problem if I plug in the problematic monitor + another monitor. The two "good" monitors work fine if plugged in together without the 3rd problematic one

What I've tried:

- Uninstalling and re-installing ubuntu desktop, xserver-xorg, and gdm3
- I was going to re-install Ubuntu itself but the behavior still happened on the live install USB so I didn't do that
- Switching monitors, cables
- Forcing config with xrandr (though the xrandr output below looks fine as is)

```
base ❯ xrandr -q | grep connected
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 connected 1440x2560+4000+0 right (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
DP-2 connected primary 2560x1440+1440+609 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
DP-3 connected 1440x2560+0+101 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
None-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

```
base ❯ sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:07:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001E07sv00001462sd00003711bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : TU102 [GeForce RTX 2080 Ti Rev. A]
manual_install: True
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-418-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-515 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-515-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-510-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-510 - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

```
base ❯ neofetch
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               xxx@xxx
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           -------------------------
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: B450M DS3H
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 5.15.0-46-generic
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 1 hour, 16 mins
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 2369 (dpkg), 16 (snap)
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: zsh 5.8.1
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1440x2560, 2560x1440, 1440x2560
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: GNOME 42.4
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Mutter
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: Adwaita
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Yaru [GTK2/3]
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3]
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: alacritty
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 2600X (12) @ 3.600GHz
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti Rev. A
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         Memory: 4594MiB / 48131MiB
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it will solve your issue but it helped with similar problem:
(user yalin) [Second monitor not working via USB-C](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1400279/second-monitor-not-working-via-usb-c)
and the original solution is here:
(user thomasbangels) https://askubuntu.com/a/1134579/1185670

open file /lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-kms.conf as administrator

`sudo nano /lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-kms.conf`

and comment last line

```
# This file was generated by nvidia-prime
# Set value to 0 to disable modesetting
# options nvidia-drm modeset=1
```

then run `sudo prime-select nvidia` and restar the computer,

in my case the order of systems in GRUB changed (2 ubuntus switched places) and on main screen with resolution up to 2560x1440 I had to switch it to 1920x1080 - because after scaling main screen I was only seeing left corner of it. But at least the external monitor is working properly which is kind nice

Comment: This solved the problem for me.