# Ubuntu USB-C to HDMI adapter not working

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, usb, xrandr

I have a laptop with a USB-C port, where I am trying to use a [BENFEI USB-C to HDMI adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B966RY24) in order to display something on an external monitor. However, even though my USB-C port definitely supports DP (it worked at an office a few months ago), it is no longer working for me.

The output of `lsusb` shows something called a "USB Type-C Digital AV Adapter":

```
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0bda:0316 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB3.0-CRW
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 343c:0000 xxxxxxxx USB Type-C Digital AV Adapter
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04d9:a067 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. USB Gaming Mouse
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 04f2:b71a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HD Webcam
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 048d:6004 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. ITE Device(8291)
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And here is the output of `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   2560x1440     40.00*+ 165.00
```

`nvidia-smi` returns `NVIDIA-SMI 525.105.17   Driver Version: 525.105.17   CUDA Version: 12.0`, and `sudo prime-select query` returns `nvidia`, though changing that to `intel` doesn't make a difference.

`journalctl` displays the following when the adapter is plugged in:

```
Jun 20 11:08:45 morin-y kernel: usb 3-5: new low-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
Jun 20 11:08:46 morin-y kernel: usb 3-5: No LPM exit latency info found, disabling LPM.
Jun 20 11:08:46 morin-y kernel: usb 3-5: New USB device found, idVendor=343c, idProduct=0000, bcdDevice= 0.00
Jun 20 11:08:46 morin-y kernel: usb 3-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jun 20 11:08:46 morin-y kernel: usb 3-5: Product: USB Type-C Digital AV Adapter
Jun 20 11:08:46 morin-y kernel: usb 3-5: Manufacturer: xxxxxxxx
Jun 20 11:08:46 morin-y kernel: usb 3-5: SerialNumber: 000000000000
```

I attempted editing `nvidia-kms.conf` as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1400281/602498), with no success. Is there anything else I can try?