# Ubuntu 22.04 : No display signal from device

Tags: 22.04, external-monitor

I recently installed ubuntu 22.04 in my laptop. I have an external monitor (Dell p2319H) which I have connected over display port. However the display doesnot seem to be recognised (monitor displays "No display signal from device"). Furthermore when I open display on setting it doesnt show their either. Please note that I have windows dual boot and on windows the monitor does display without any issues.

The graphics card that I have is - GA104GLM [RTX A3000 Mobile]

Any idea whats I can do get it working

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a fresh new HP Zbook Fury with the same GPU as yours. Hence I make the assumption that we share the configuration.
Apparently, HDMI port is not working with the Intel integrated graphics using Linux drivers.
In order to make it work, you can fresh install new NVIDIA drivers with the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa -y
sudo apt update
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

Now you can see the recommended drivers and the name of your GPU. Personally the recommended one (nvidia-520-open) crashed my computer so simply use:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-520
reboot
```

Normally, the second monitor should work as a charm and you can leave your BIOS to hybrid mode for GPU.

Futhermore, you could install nvidia-prime via the Ubuntu extension manager in order to switch between GPU (eg. Intel for battery life and NVIDIA for processing... even if you can select the *NVIDIA on demand* option)

Hope it solves your problem ;)

Comment: Thanks it worked for me

Comment: I used a slightly different version, but it was the one apt marked as "recommended". Works, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar situation in which the external monitor would no longer be detected by my laptop. Running `xrandr` would only show the internal laptop display. This problem plagued me for months but I discovered completely by chance that running `lspci` effectively refreshes the device display list. I have no idea why this works but it has worked consistently for me...

Comment: This is so silly, but works for me! I've lost my mind for days!

Comment: I was just about to restart my laptop. Then I saw this answer. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Let me offer a few ideas.

Shutdown completely and turn on but close the lid immediately. That might for the system to switch to alternate output.

Try upgrading or downgrading Nvidia drives. If for come reason you're running the Nouveau driver then switch to Nvidia drivers.

Do you have an HDMI cable you can try?

Maybe forcing restart to display driver.

```
sudo systemctl restart gdm
```

Let us know if anything helps or what does fix this issue.

Comment: This occurs with my setup (dock, 2 DP Monitors, Built-in Monitor on/off): when I open certain apps (e.g. IntelliJ) DP monitors go out of signal and I need to turn the dock off, close the app via the built-in monitor and turn the dock on again. Even weirder, if instead of click the icon directly I go to context menu and select new window, everything works just fine. Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

That's what I did for my notebok with an external Dell P2319H.

1. Removed local configurations for monitors with `rm .config/monitors.xml*`
2. I did a reconfigure of **gdm3** (gnome-display-manager) with:

   sudo systemctl start gdm3.service
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
3. Rebooted with my notebook lid closed.

Comment: Thanks for this! My monitor just didn't work (no signal) despite my NixOS act like it's connected to the monitor after I changed the method of connecting from HDMI to DisplayPort. After deleting the `monitors.xml` and rebooting, the display connection is back to life!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on an HP laptop with an nVidia GPU.  In the BIOS (yes, I use Secure Boot), I change the graphics from 'hybrid' to 'discrete'.  That immediately fixed it for me.
In searching many sites, I never did find a solution / setting so it would with both GPU (hybrid) running.
Hope this help.