# dual-monitors - main screen displays only 1/4 of image

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, xrandr

I'm using two monitors, main one is 4k and second one is 2k resolution. Everything is connected to my laptop through a usb-c dock (see bellow for references).

When connecting both monitors, the main monitor only displays 1/4 of the screen :
[what image is vs what it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DipS.png)

If I set main monitor's resolution to 2k I can see the whole image.

If I connect only the main monitor, I can see the whole image.

Setting second monitor to lower resolution won't fix the problem.

If I connect the second monitor to the dock and main one directly to the laptop hdmi port, everything works fine.

On windows everything works fine with both monitors connected to the dock, which makes me think that it's a problem with ubuntu and not with my usb-c dock.

My laptop is a Lenovo X1 Carbon Gen9 and my dock is a thinkpad universal usb-c dock (40AY). [According to official specs](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/pd029622-display-and-video-output-configurations-docking-stations), the dock should display both screens at right resolution.

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.1.

What I tried without success :

- Disable Secure-Boot
- Erase ~/.config/monitors.xml
- [Answers to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105332/external-monitor-not-working-ubuntu-nvidia/1134579#1134579)

Thanks for your help !

Comment: usb-c or thunderbolt? if usb-c, you're using DisplayLink, did you install the Linux DisplayLink drivers?

Comment: does that happen in a wayland or XServer session? If XSession, post the output of `xrandr`into your question...

Comment: I did install the DisplayLink drivers and switched to Xorg (apparently wayland is not supported) but my second screen cannot be enabled. It is disabled by default and switching it on won't turn on the screen. 

It happens in a wayland session.