# Installing Ubuntu 16.04 on MSI GE72MVR, system freezes when I restart

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, msi

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 beside Windows 10 on my MSI laptop GE72MVR. The process goes well until the last action: rebooting, then it freezes.

I had to shutdown manually (long press on power). I can start Ubuntu normally but can't access my session. Guest session works fine (I thought it was a graphical issue, does that mean it's not?).

If I select **"Try Ubuntu"** in the installer it will also freeze. I can just see the wallpaper and the bar on top.

I'm using an USB stick made on Windows with Rufus and the .iso file for desktop 16.04.3. I also tried to make a bootable usb from my other Linux computer, but the same thing occurs.

Hardware: cpu intel i7700, gpu nvidia gtx1070.

Comment: Boot with `nomodeset`, then install Nvidia drivers.

Comment: I've just done it and the problem is now solved. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely with graphic card driver.
In grub entery, press E and in the new page add `nomodeset` before `quiet splash`. This disable default driver. Press F10 to return to login page. 
Follow the instruction in : 
[How can I uninstall a nvidia driver completely ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely)
 to remove old driver. Then reboot and login in using `nomodeset` again. 
Then you should install new driver.
Don't download driver from Nvidia website. It's likely to be incompatible. You should download it from ppa repository:

`sudo add-apt-repositorty ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`

`sudo app-get update`

`sudo app-get install nvidia-381`

Then restart computer and you'll be able to login normally.

Comment: It appears that i had no driver installed at all (the instruction in the link returned that nothing had been deleted). Nevertheless, installing the nvidia-381 from the repo you gave me fixed my issue. Thank you son much !

Answer (score 1):

I got this kind of problem multiple times when trying to install linux distributions.

If you used the same ISO file (i.e. you copied it on a USB stick and flashed it without re-downloading) then your file may contain errors.
Try downloading it again from a torrent ; there should also be an option in installer to check installation files, but I think re-downloading is the safest option before trying anything else.

You can verify your downloads by performing `mdsum <filename>`, `sha1sum <filename>` and `sha256sum <filename`, comparing the values of the checksums to the corresponding values found at http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ for the version of Ubuntu you are downloading.

Answer (score 0):

If ubuntu is not your primary OS, I prefer to disable video support (for my MSI GP62-6QE, it's nVidia 950m), ~*at least until nVidia publish stable driver for their cards in linux*~, by adding this line in grub command line:

```
nouveau.modeset=0 i915.preliminary_hw_support=1
```

It's helped me to make Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 run smoothly in my MSI