# Why is my ubuntu studio 16.04.3 LTS installer freezing?

Tags: system-installation, usb, ubuntu-studio

I made an installation USB from my Mac OS via unetbootin. I can boot from the stick and see the options to try out the OS, install it etc. Whichever option I pick the screen freezes and looks [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qeBb.jpg) What could have went wrong? My PC has an MSI B350M PRO-VDH which I updated prior to trying the install, but the update seemed to have finished with no issues (and I can access the bios alright). Could it still have anything to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it had to do with the NVidia graphics card. This did the trick:

[Installing Ubuntu 16.04 on MSI GE72MVR, system freezes when I restart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/949496/installing-ubuntu-16-04-on-msi-ge72mvr-system-freezes-when-i-restart?rq=1)